# In node.js how to get the result of the other module function in current module?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I need the result of other module function in my current module.How can i do this.

module1.js

```
         var module2=require('./lib/module2');
         module2.getValue();
```

Now i want that 'true' returned in the getValue method.How can i get here.

In other languages below code will work

```
var result=module2.getValue();
```

But in node.js we have to use callback method to get that value.How can i do that.

module2.js

```
exports.getValue=function(){

   console.log('getValue method called.');
   return true;

};
```

Finally i changed my module1 code also but i'm not getting that result as true.Below is my updated module1 code

```
     var module2=require('./lib/module2');
     module2.getValue();
```

Below is my exact code

server.js

```
     var express = require('express')
   , http = require('http');

     var app = express();

   app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

   var server = http.createServer(app);

   var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    server.listen(8000);

   var cradle=require('cradle');

     new(cradle.Connection)('https://mydomain.iriscouch.com/', 5984, {
                cache: true,
                raw: false
            });


            cradle.setup({
                host: 'mydomain.iriscouch.com',
                cache: true,
                raw: false
              });


              var c = new(cradle.Connection);
              exports.connObj=c;

                 var notifications=require('./lib/Notifications');
                 var notificationId="89b92aa8256cad446913118601000feb";
                 console.log(notifications.getNotificatiosById(notificationId));
```

Notifications.js

```
        var appModule=require('../server');
        var connectionObj=appModule.connObj;
        var db = connectionObj.database('notifications');


        exports.getNotificatiosById=function(notificationId){

        db.get(notificationId, function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);//im getting output for this line while running server.js file
        return true;
  });

     };
```

Comment: `var result=module2.getValue();` is just fine so long as your method is synchronous.

Comment: @generalhenry var result=module2.getValue();
console.log(result);  //i tried this code but it always showing result as undefined.

Comment: strange, try in module1 `console.dir(module2);` and `console.log(module2.getValue.toString());` to see what you're getting.

Comment: @generalhenry for first one im getting [object object]...for second im getting following function........                                 function(){

   console.log('getValue method called.');
   return true;

};

Comment: @generalhenry..Is there any other way to get that result.

Comment: Try `module.exports.getValue = function(){` instead of `exports.getValue = function(){`. /edit: which version of node are you running? And on which operating system?

Comment: @JanŚwięcki node version is v0.6.17
OS is Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @JanŚwięcki i have tried that module.exports.getValue()...But im getting result as undefined

Comment: @user2138629 ok. So you are saying that when in `module1.js` you do `console.log(module2.getValue.toString())` you get string representation of your function, but when (in the same code) you do `console.log(module2.getValue())` you get `undefined`? If yes then please show us exact code you are using in both files (i.e. copy and paste).

Comment: @JanŚwięcki yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss. Updated my exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have this method:

```
exports.getNotificatiosById = function (notificationId) {

  db.get(notificationId, function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc); //im getting output for this line while running server.js file
    return true;
  });

};
```

There is and inner callback function. In this case it is impossible for `getNotificatiosById` to return value from inside of `db.get`. You should probably read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9596276/1637178).

I don't know which database system you use, but maybe in the API there is a synchronous version, i.e. `db.getSync`. Then we could do something like this:

```
exports.getNotificatiosById = function (notificationId) {

  return db.getSync(notificationId);

};
```

But basically in NodeJS we almost always use (and want to use) callback functions because of the non-blocking way of executing script. Regardless of your knowledge about this stuff I recommend [Introduction to Node.js](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I) video in which creator of node explains alot.