# passing arguments to callback

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback

How can I pass arguments to a callback function in this specific scenario.

I have a function that gets an object with callbacks like this

```
function doSomething({ callbackSuccess : myFunction, callbackError : myOtherFunction})
```

how can I pass arguments to myFunction or to myOtherFunction?

Like, if myOtherFunction gets a msg parameter like this

```
function myOtherFunction(msg) {
   alert(msg);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplest of all**:

```
function dosomething(callback) {
    //some code-poetry;
    callback(1, 2, 3); //the callback is back!!!
}

function foo(a, b, c) {//this will be my callback
    alert("I got some parameters")
}

dosomething(foo); //the function call
```

Best explanation for a callback function:[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o)

**A simple defination would be**:the callback function is called at a certain point in the future when some code or a function completes execution.

Answer (score 2):

Just like you pass them to any other function:

```
function doSomething(callbacks) {
    callbacks.callbackSuccess('foo', 'bar');
}
```

If you mean you want to pass them "at the time of passing them into `doSomething`":

```
doSomething({ callbackSuccess : function () { myFunction('foo'); }, ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
// function def
function doSomething(a) {
}

// calling function
doSomething({
    callbackSuccess : function() {
        myFunction(msg);
    },
    callbackError : myOtherFunction
});
```