# Are all Node.js callback functions asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm working on learning Node.js and all I hear in every tutorial is "Node is asynchronous and no -blocking!"

I've heard in regular browser JavaScript only certain things such as AJAX calls can be made asynchronous or non-blocking (using callbacks)... Is this true of Node.js as well, or are all Node.js callback functions made asynchronous/non-blocking?

Comment: yes. this is the nature of javascript not node.js specific.

Comment: @zsong That isn't entirely accurate.

Comment: that is totally not accurate. read the spec. nothing about sync/async or blocking/non-blocking or io at all

Comment: It isn't the callback that's asynchronous. It's the function you're passing the callback to that's asynchronous, and therefore requires a callback. And not every function that takes a callback does so because it's going to do something async.

Answer (score 17):

> are all Node.js callback functions made asynchronous/non-blocking?

No. Only I/O is usually asynchronous, but many other callbacks are synchronous. Always check the docs.

Examples of async functions:

- Async [Filesystem](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) access (they have sync counterparts without callbacks, though)
- Timers (`setTimeout`)
- `process.nextTick`, `setImmediate`
- most database connections
- network connections
- [Promises](http://promisesaplus.com/)

Examples of sync callbacks:

- [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) (depends on when the event is fired)
- [Array iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) methods like `forEach`
- [Array `sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) comparator callbacks
- [String `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) match callbacks

See also [Are all javascript callbacks asynchronous? If not, how do I know which are?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19083357/1048572) (including some other examples).

Comment: That isn't entirely accurate.  You're right that I/O is multithreaded and the rest isnt, but many other callbacks are still asynchronous and called in a separate call stack.

Comment: What other callbacks do you mean?

Comment: When you pass a function as an argument, it doesn't mean it is a callback. For `forEach` is's iterator and for `EventEmitter` it's listener

Comment: @vkurchatkin: They're still [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), aren't them?

Comment: @Brad: Which other callbacks do you mean?

Comment: @Bergi it looks like they are, generally speaking

Comment: @Bergi `zlib` and `crypto` has async capabilities, but they are not IO

Comment: @vkurchatkin: A function passed to another function for that other function to invoke is a callback. Doesn't matter if the callback will be invoked synchronously or asynchronously. The ECMAScript spec refers to the function passed to `.forEach()` for example as a "callback".

Comment: @vkurchatkin: zlib seems to do interprocess communication (via a stream), crypto seems to read from `/dev/random` - which I would both consider IO. Sure there are examples where code uses async capabilities for being non-blocking without doing IO, so I've generalized my statement by adding a "*usually*" :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'm just talking about "other asynchronous callbacks" from Brad's comment, I agree about that part of your answer. To stop off-topic here is an interesting post by isaacs: http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony here talks more about consistency (always sync or always async), but still relevant

Answer (score 4):

When you pass a callback to a function, you expect that function to call your callback function some other time.  However, it isn't automatically asynchronous.

Suppose I have this code:

```
function callSomething(callback) {
  callback();
}

function theCallback() {
  // Do something time consuming here
}

callSomething(theCallback);
```

In this case, we're passing a callback, but the callback gets called immediately on the existing call stack.  This is considered **bad practice** and is **strongly discouraged** in Node.js.  If you want to call a callback fairly immediately, use `process.nextTick()`:

```
function callSomething(callback) {
  process.nextTick(callback);
}
```

So the direct answer to your question is mostly yes.  When you specify a callback to functions in Node.js, by convention they will be called on another callstack at a later point in time.  But if you are using some bad code from someone who didn't know how to follow this convention, there is no guarantee.

Comment: True in general. Also worth mentioning that `setImmediate` could be used and I've heard couple of node core members saying that it's better to use it than `nextTick` to avoid `nextTick` specific problems (IO starvation mostly)

Comment: @vkurchatkin Interesting, I hadn't heard of setImmediate.  I'm definitely swapping this out in some of my projects!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15349865/362536

Answer (score 2):

Nope, they are not automatically asynchronous. Consider this code:

```
function foo(array, filter, callback) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (filter(array[i])) result.push(array[i]);
    }

    callback(result);
}
```

And now imagine a program like this:

```
foo([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], function() { while(true); }, console.log);
console.log('Blocking?');
```

If `foo` would be asynchronous then `Blocking?` would immediatly appear, but it does not!

---

You can be pretty sure, however, that most / all of the standard library taking a callback is non-blocking async code. Most of it also has a `Sync` counterpart.