# Are promises only for async operations?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I was wondering if I could use promises with my countdown timer. My code looks something like this:

```
function countdown(duration, callback) {
  ...
}

function sayHi() {
  console.log('hi');
}
```

and I call it by doing something like

```
countdown(15, sayHi);
```

Is there a way I could do this instead?

```
countdown(15).then(sayHi);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/amhLwqd4/1/) is a JSFiddle of my current code.

Comment: That would be an asynch operation, wouldn't it. ?

Comment: Google about promises, then you'll be able to answer your question.

Comment: Is it really? All the code inside my `countdown` function is synchronous, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amhLwqd4/1/) is what it looks like right now. I basically just call the callback manually.

Comment: "*Are promises only for async operations?*" - Yes. "*Is there a way I could do `countdown(15).then(sayHi);` instead?*" - Yes. Show us what `...` is and we may be able to help you with the transformation.

Comment: Count down timer implies asynchronicity. My bad

Comment: @meh_programmer: `setInterval`, which you are using inside your `countdown` function, is *not synchronous*.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry about that, I updated my post with a JSFiddle. And oh, I see that makes sense.

Comment: @Bergi I want to choose an answer so this question can be resolved. Do you think the answer by ShanShan is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, promises are a way to "hide" callbacks. For your example, you could use promises like this:

```
function countdown(duration) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // wait for duration and resolve
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, duration);
    });
}

function sayHi() {
    console.log('hi');
}

countdown(1000).then(sayHi);
```

Comment: Not all callbacks can be hidden using promises.

Comment: Do you have an example? Instead of passing the callback as an argument, it goes to the `then()` and no other change is needed.

Comment: [Many examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21884813/1048572), actually :-) Your code is fine, I just disagree with the generality of the statement "*promises are a way to "hide" callbacks*".

Comment: Ah, I see. I just realised that when a callback is called multiple times (sync or async), a promise can't (easily?) replace it. That's where pipes/streams come in play in NodeJS. Interesting.

Comment: Exactly - promises can never be used in such situations. They're only suited for callbacks that are called exactly once (and usually asynchronous).

Answer (score 2):

A promise is suitable for any operation that won't necessarily run immediately.

Javascript is single-threaded. So if you call a function, it will necessarily run immediately on the same thread. A promise is a convenient way to run code some time later (still on the same thread, but as part of a different event handler).

So in the case of a timeout, when the callback should be called later, using a promise is a good idea.

And if you're unsure whether to use a promise or a simple callback, both serve more-or-less the same purpose, but promises normally make the code more readable.

[ES7 async-await](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) is even more readable!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Gave you an upvote. Also thanks for the link to the async-await, that looks pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

yes you can `resolve` them at your own specific time like.use closures to escape from bad response from multiple calls simultaneously.

```
function countdown(duration, callback) {
 var deferred = Promise.defer();
    (function(duration,deferred){setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    },duration);
  })(duration,deferred);
}
```

Previous one is outdated check this one.

```
  function countdown(duration, callback) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve();
            }, duration);
        });


}
```

Comment: There is no `Promise.defer` function.

Comment: have a look @Bergi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred

Comment: Those are not ES6 promises. The second sentence on the page you linked is a deprecation notice.

Comment: ya its outdated i used them long time ago Thanks

Comment: @ngLover `countdown` returns `TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function`

Comment: @ngLover _"Previous one is outdated"_ `Promise` constructor `new Promise()` requires a `resolver` function to be passed as parameter

Comment: that was an deffered object check out link

Answer (score 0):

```
function countdown(duration) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(duration--);
      if (!duration) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
countdown(15).then(function() { console.log("DONE"); });
```

Comment: It's more reasonable to promisify `setTimeout` and use that as an asynchronous primitive. Using `console.log` inside `setInterval` like you did gives you none of the advantages of promises.

Comment: @Bergi: The promise is for the end of countdown, just as it seems to be in OP's post. The `console.log` simulates the UI updates one would do for the duration of the countdown. I guess I took "countdown" literally.

Comment: Yeah, but if you're using promises, you should be doing the UI updates from promises as well :-)

Comment: Why reinvent `setTimeout`?