# Is Array.forEach may let other contexts to be executed before executing all elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, v8, nonblocking

In node.js.

Is Array.forEach may let other contexts to be executed before executing all elements?

How actually it works ?

I know that (correct me if something wrong please):

- The top execution context in the call stack is the context that will be executed first.
- No two execution contexts are executed at the same time.

Is that mean:
 - If we use loop such as (for .. in ..) there is no other execution context will be executed until the entire loop is executed and if we use forEach (which I think is creating an execution context for each element) may let other contexts that may be added by the browser for Ajax or by node.js for finished I/O operation to the call stack to be executed before the executing the callbacks for each element ?

Comment: Node.js is single-threaded. There is no concurrency.

Comment: "(which I think is creating an execution context for each element)" It is not. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous?rq=1) might clear things up.

Comment: Also have a look at [Are all Node.js callback functions asynchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21884258/1048572)