# API should be either %100 synchronous or %100 asynchronous example

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

While i'm studying https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg , i'm stucked at a point. I'm quoting it below :

> It is very important for APIs to be either 100% synchronous or 100%
>   asynchronous. Consider this example:

```
// WARNING!  DO NOT USE!  BAD UNSAFE HAZARD!    
function maybeSync(arg, cb) {     
    if (arg) {      
        cb();       
        return;       
    }

    fs.stat('file', cb);
```

> This API is hazardous because in the following case:

```
maybeSync(true, () => {       
     foo();     
});     
bar();
```

> It is not clear whether foo() or bar() will be called first.

**I didn't understand why it is not clear whether foo() or bar() will be called first. Because arg is true and maybeSync function works synchronously. Thus everything works synchronously and foo() will be called before bar(), i think. Why this is not true for this case?**

> The following approach is much better:

```
function definitelyAsync(arg, cb) {       
    if (arg) {      
        process.nextTick(cb);       
        return;
    }

    fs.stat('file', cb);    
}
```

Comment: It's not clear whether `foo()` or `bar()` will be called first *unless you look at the internals of the `maybeSync()` function.* And even then you don't really know what'll happen at runtime unless you can guarantee that the values you pass it will *always* be of a certain type. You should be able to rely on a particular function always being synchronous or always asynchronous without having to look at how the function is implemented.

Comment: @nnnnnn  , OK I got it. One more question please, what is () => { ... } in the second parameter of maybeSync() function ? I cannot search it on google :S

Comment: They're called arrow functions, and are part of the new ES6 (EcmaScript 6). `() => { ... }` is the shorthand equivalent of `function() { ... }` - but beware there are also some differences in scope.

Comment: Have a look at [Are callbacks in node.js either always asynchronous or always synchronous? Or can they be “sometimes one, sometimes the other”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31944806/1048572) and [What is the intention behind clause 2.2.4 of Promise/A+ spec?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36932244/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Execution is not clear because `fs.stat()` is async and executes at soonest on next tick, meaning that `bar()` will always execute before `foo()`.

However, by introducing the `if (arg)` clause where `cb()` is executed immediately, then `foo()` will execute before `bar()` - this is in sync.
Thus, `maybeSync()` has no predictability without knowing what `arg` is, before execution.

The `definitelyAsync()` forces always async execution, by scheduling a call to `cb()` inside the `if (arg)` branch, which will always result in `bar()` being executed before `foo()` regardless of the `arg` value.