# Callback meaning in MDN

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the meaning of callback that is on the MDN, for example [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), how to recognize the callback that used in there is sync or async?

Comment: Maybe the fact that it returns the result directly, i.e. you don’t have to wait for events in order to use `[].filter`. You can directly chain it: `[].filter(…).reduce(…).toString()`, etc.

Comment: @Xufox not really. `setTimeout` returns a handle to the timer (timer id), but runs its callback asynchronously. Promises return... well, a promise. But the resolve/reject handlers may execute asynchronously.

Comment: "Callback" in that context is perhaps not the best term, since callback suggests something happens (subject of the request), *then* the callback is called. In this case, that's not what happens, the so-called callback *is the subject*. If you're passing it to a function that's using it immediately and the request is not subject to any delay (like `array.filter`), it's going to be run inline.

Comment: why should the callback be async? It's just a function

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083357/are-all-javascript-callbacks-asynchronous-if-not-how-do-i-know-which-are?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @JaredFarrish the spec calls it `callbackfn` http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - And I think it's not the best term in that context. `:)` Calling it a handler in this situation would be much more explicit to what it's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to figure out the meaning using the following approach: it will be asynchronous if the API itself does asynchronous operations. For example AJAX, Web Sockets, WebRTC, Web Workers are asynchronous APIs.

All other Web browser APIs like `Array.prototype` functions are all synchronous.

That is, *callback* doesn't mean asynchronous or synchronous, but just *you need to give a function as argument with some input parameters or just a parameterless function*.

It would be great if asynchronous functions would be suffixed with *Async*. For example, `setTimeoutAsync(...)`, or `sendAsync`, but this just a subjective (but very effective) coding convention not used in JavaScript (it's sad...).

Comment: Node has that convention you mentioned in reverse. Synchronous ones get named explicitly. :)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Yeah... it does the reverse because Node works on top of the idea of non-blocking I/O so you know that something with `Sync` particle may produce performance issues with high concurrency enviornments...