# Trying to connect to the Foursquare API and failing because "Callback uri is not valid for this consumer"

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, foursquare, mapbox, jquery-bbq

I'm going through Foursquare's [tutorial](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/tutorial) and am getting this error message when I try to load the page:

> Connecting failed
>
> This app has a configuration problem and was unable
>   to connect to your Foursquare account.
>
> Cause of error: Callback uri is not valid for this consumer

The code is the exact same as the sample code with my credentials subbed in. Is my Foursquare Client id not the right thing to use as the apiKey under config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>foursquare :: Explore Sample</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" id="jquery"></script>


  <link href="/styles/leaflet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/styles/apisamples.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="/scripts/apisamples.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/third_party/jquery.ba-bbq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/third_party/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/third_party/wax.leaf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100%; }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    /* Give our markers a background image */
    .leaflet-marker-icon {
      background: url(https://foursquare.com/img/pin-blue-transparent.png);
      padding: 6px;
      padding-bottom: 17px;
      top: -6px;
      left: -6px;
      }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var config = {
    apiKey: '[my Foursquare Client id]',
    authUrl: 'https://foursquare.com/',
    apiUrl: 'https://api.foursquare.com/'
  };


  //<![CDATA[

  /* Attempt to retrieve access token from URL. */
  function doAuthRedirect() {
    var redirect = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
    var url = config.authUrl + 'oauth2/authenticate?response_type=token&client_id=' + config.apiKey +
        '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect) +
        '&state=' + encodeURIComponent($.bbq.getState('req') || 'users/self');
    window.location.href = url;
  };

  if ($.bbq.getState('access_token')) {
    // If there is a token in the state, consume it
    var token = $.bbq.getState('access_token');
    $.bbq.pushState({}, 2)
  } else if ($.bbq.getState('error')) {
  } else {
    doAuthRedirect();
  }

  /* HTML 5 geolocation. */
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {
    var lat = data['coords']['latitude'];
    var lng = data['coords']['longitude'];
    /* Create map. */
    var map = new L.Map('map_canvas')
      .setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), 15);
    var mapboxUrl = 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[my Mapbox username].[my map id].jsonp';
    wax.tilejson(mapboxUrl, function(tilejson) {
      map.addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson));
    });

    /* Query foursquare API for venue recommendations near the current location. */
    $.getJSON(config.apiUrl + 'v2/venues/explore?ll=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&oauth_token=' + window.token, {}, function(data) {
      venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];
      /* Place marker for each venue. */
      for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
        /* Get marker's location */
        var latLng = new L.LatLng(
          venues[i]['venue']['location']['lat'],
          venues[i]['venue']['location']['lng']
        );
        /* Build icon for each icon */
        var leafletIcon = L.Icon.extend({
          iconUrl: venues[i]['venue']['categories'][0]['icon'],
          shadowUrl: null,
          iconSize: new L.Point(32,32),
          iconAnchor: new L.Point(16, 41),
          popupAnchor: new L.Point(0, -51)
        });
        var icon = new leafletIcon();
        var marker = new L.Marker(latLng, {icon: icon})
          .bindPopup(venues[i]['venue']['name'], { closeButton: false })
          .on('mouseover', function(e) { this.openPopup(); })
          .on('mouseout', function(e) { this.closePopup(); });
        map.addLayer(marker);
      }
    })
  })
  //]]>
  </script>


</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cause of error: Callback uri is not valid for this consumer

A callback url is a webpage loaded after your web app has been verified. In this case, you need to specify a page for to send data to after authentication.

Double check your Foursquare credentials and update the `callback uri` to a valid link. [The tutorial your shared](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/tutorial) uses `https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/samples/explore`, but you'll need to specify the url where this page is hosted.

Comment: By callback uri, did you mean the redirect_uri parameter in the url variable? I changed the parameter to the link you provided but am now getting a "We couldn't find the page you're looking for." message. In my app settings (accessible through the Foursquare developer site), the Redirect URI was already set to that URI.

Comment: updated answer explaining callback urls. please see additional SO questions for [more information regarding callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o).