# AJAX global variable? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have i think a global variable problem. Watch this:

```
function more_elems() {
var ret = [];

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    ret[i] =
    {
    id: JSONObject[i].id,
    nombre: JSONObject[i].nombre,
    mensaje: JSONObject[i].mensaje,
    ult_m: JSONObject[i].ultima_modificacion
    };

}
alert(ret);
}
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","somewesite.com",true);
xmlhttp.send();
return ret;
```

So im trying to return the ret array but it returns undefined. However if i do an alert inside the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() it does show the array with the json object. I'm not sure what the problem is =/.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to understand what a callback is ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o

Comment: Even tough your variable scope is correct, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/2752041). It might help you understand better variables scopes and globals. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous. So the `ret array` will not be set when you invoke immediately after `xmlhttp.send().`

Have any mehtod and pass the value once the value of `ret array` is set. Ty something like below,

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
             var JSONObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
             for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            ret[i] ={
               id: JSONObject[i].id,
               nombre: JSONObject[i].nombre,
               mensaje: JSONObject[i].mensaje,
               ult_m: JSONObject[i].ultima_modificacion
            };

        }
        onAjaxSuccess(ret);
      }
    }

function onAjaxSuccess(arr){
    alert(arr);
}
```

Comment: Yup , that works! thanks. But what if im trying to return ret on the main function -> function more_elems(). 'Cause that is what im trying to achieve. Returning ret array on that function.

Comment: Hope it helped. You cant do that as I said Ajax is asynchronous and by the time you return at the end of the function the `ret array` wont be set with the values. Hope it helped. Don't mind to mark it as correct answer ;)

Comment: Right.. well i'll have to figure out how to do it then. Thanks and will do :)