# Prevent second ajax call while first one complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know there are so many questions in stackoverflow regarding this type of issues, but still, those wont help me to solve my one

this is the jquery code

```
function _get_activities_ajax() {
    $(".activity-accordian h3").click(function() {
        var catrgory      = $(this).attr("data-subject");
        var catId      = $(this).attr("id");
        if($("#"+catId+"-wrap ul").children().length==0) { 
        $("#"+catId+"-wrap").append("<div class='preloader'></div>");
            $.ajax({
                url: _getActivityAjax,
                data: {catrgory: catrgory},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    $(".preloader").remove();
                    $("#"+catId+"-wrap").append(result);
                },
                error: function(e) {

                }  
            });
        }
        $(".activity-accordian h3").removeClass("active-header").removeClass("header-1");
        $(this).addClass("active-header");

        $(".categ-content ul").css("display","none");  
        $("#"+catId+"-wrap ul").css("display","block"); 
    });  
}
```

this is written to get data sets to an accordion.

i need to prevent the second call until the first one complete. any help would appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: you can use a variable which holds the status of your call. For example: `var done = false;`. And in your `success()` method you can say: `done = true;`

Comment: try @VDesign suggestion..

Comment: Yeah! @VDesign I'll Suggest you to make that comment as answer. and OP please Try it. +1 VDesign.

Comment: Thanks to VDesign! You save my time! and also thanks to Vedant Terkar,  Jai, Praveen and Ehsan Sajjad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a variable that holds the status of your Ajax call.

**JS**

```
function _get_activities_ajax() {

    //Variable status ajax call
    var status = true;

    $(".activity-accordian h3").click(function() {
        var catrgory      = $(this).attr("data-subject");
        var catId      = $(this).attr("id");

        if($("#"+catId+"-wrap ul").children().length==0  && status) { //check if true

            //New ajax call so status set to false
            status = false;

            $.ajax({
                url: _getActivityAjax,
                data: {catrgory: catrgory},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {

                    //set status done to true
                    status = true;
                },
                error: function(e) {


                    //if error also set status to true
                    status = true;

                }  
            });
        }

        ...
    });  
}
```

Comment: Good one! +1. But I think that `var status=false;` should be outside function body and `status=false` should be in function **after ajax call** and you should check `status` variable before making call .

Comment: @VedantTerkar How is it _Really Good one!_? What is status doing here just updating the var values.

Comment: I have updated to code in my anwser. I forgot the if statement.

Comment: @Jai It is good because it is simple. and +1 for enthusiasm of User. But still this answer needs correction.

Comment: @VedantTerkar that's fine seems `.off()` has to be used in this case, that would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks VDesign! you save my time!, Thanks to VedantTerkar, Jai and Praveen

Answer (score 2):

Previously these kind of issues are simply avoid using **`async`** property in ajax.  Since this will freeze the GUI for few seconds, they improvised using [**`callbacks`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o).

Here in your code, write the another ajax call within the success callback of the first.

**example:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: _getActivityAjax,
    data: {catrgory: catrgory},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        $(".preloader").remove();
        $("#"+catId+"-wrap").append(result);
        //Place your second ajax      
    },
    error: function(e) {

    }  
});
```