# How to get callback function value in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my Logic in one of my `controller` method

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {

   var empRole;
   EmpModel.findById(empId, null ,function(err, emp) {

      if(emp) {
         empRole = emp.role;          
      }
   });

   console.log("Emp Role : " + empRole);      // This will return undefined
};
```

How can I get the value of `empRole` from the call back function

Comment: "[How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)" will likely be a worthwhile read. Though it uses Ajax via jQuery as the example, the same restraints and options apply to all asynchronous operations, including database queries with Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to the index function and inside the "IF" condition use the callback to pass the value to the caller.

Example:

```
exports.index = function(callback) {

   var empRole;
   EmpModel.findById(empId, null ,function(err, emp) {

      if(emp) {
         empRole = emp.role;
         callback(empRole)
      }
   });


};
```

You need to invoke the index function like this:

```
index(function(emprole){
      //this function is executed once the findById completes
      console.log("Emp Role : " + empRole); 
});
```

Look into [Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o)'s in javascript along with [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to understand this better.

Comment: But i have `req, res` in functional params in `index` method.

Comment: The actual scenario is when index called i get the empId from query param `(req.query.empId)` also with optional filter params. And check if the Employee exists and grap some value from that particular employee atlast filter the all employees with necessary filter option.

Comment: Please look into Callbacks; as javascript is asynchronous return wont work. Also in the actual code if you move the console.log right after the if(emp) condition ends i.e. the } bracket you should have the value printed.