# Make function work synchronously (wait local events to get fired)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, synchronous

I'm having problems with JavaScript logic. When we have a function that needs data from event-handler to generate result, is it possible to get that data back to function? For example, if we call `Image()` object or `FileReader()` inside and wait for its `load` event to get fired in order to generate proper return result.

Simple example:

```
function imageSize(filename) {
  funcResult = false;
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    myResult = { 
      width: img.width,
      height: img.height
      }
    }
  img.src = filename;
  return funcResult;
}
```

Course, it doesn't work because `load` fires asynchronously after function has already been executed. But is there some workaround to make function **stop and listen** which is my main goal.

Or bit more complex example (that also can't work for same reason).

```
function getImageSize(file) {
  res = false;
  if (window.FileReader) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        res = {
          width  : img.width,
          height : img.height
          };
        }
      img.src = this.result;
      }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var imageSize = getImageSize(myFileInput.files[0]);
```

and handling result as (perfect: wait)

```
if (!imageSize)
  console.log('error');
else
  console.log(imageSize.width + 'x' + imageSize.height);
```

or (alternative: from event handler)

```
imageSize.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
  }
```

I'd like to make this job linear (sync) and wait for proper event handlers inside to fire, not moving job outside of function scope (especially not to global level).

My goal is to make this a one-function job, or the worst case, to define some `load` event of that function and listen for result so my strict question is "is this somehow possible and if it is, how?"

I understand how events work and know well that this approach is wrong but that's just an illustration what I was trying to accomplish during last few days.

Comment: Can always use a callback inside `imageSize`

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for suggestion. can you provide some simple example? not sure how to do that.

Comment: Check out the answer below... I had deleted it since it doesn't make the call *synchronous* - but I don't think you want that..just a way to manage what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a callback inside your function to get the size:

```
function imageSize(filename, callback) {
    funcResult = false;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var myResult = { 
            width: img.width,
            height: img.height
        }
        callback(myResult)
    }
    img.src = filename;
}
```

And use it:

```
imageSize("test.jpg", function(sizeAttributes) {
    console.log(sizeAttributes);
});
```

Comment: oh thanks, I like how simple that looks like. can you drop a few words what exactly that `callback` do in that example. it's very important to me to understand how that works. it waits for img's `load` event to get fired right?

Comment: In JavaScript, you can pass anything as a parameter, including a function. Your images `onload` call is async, so everything inside the `onload` won't be processed until the image actually loads. A `callback` is a passed in function that will be ran once your async method has completed. A *much* more detailed callback explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o

Comment: good to know that. after a quick test seems that this is exactly my missing part (I have never user callback before). thanks a million.