# Fetch APIs - Is it blocking or non-blocking code?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch-api

I've been looking at the `Fetch API` for a couple of days now.

While learning I came across the statement **"using `fetch()` doesn't block your DOM "** as it uses promises.

Happily moving forward with these tutorials and checking out some new ones, I saw a guy stating **"using `fetch()` does block your DOM"** in a presentation.

Can anyone educate me which one of the two it is?

Comment: Some guy in some presentation said so? He was probably wrong, and/or was trying to say something specific in context?

Comment: Please cite and link which guy in which presentation exactly said so, so that we may access the relevant context.

Comment: You should take that into consideration: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1330826

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `fetch` in the sense of blocking/non-blocking code comes down to the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code.

One of JavaScript's design paradigms is called [Run to Completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#run-to-completion) and it boils down to the fact that a piece of JS code that is currently executing cannot be interrupted by another piece of code. In other words, a function runs until it's finished, in a synchronous manner (also see the caveat in the end).

When you have code that is asynchronous, such as the one wrapped in a promise (which is what `fetch` is using), it gets scheduled to run later, after all the synchronous code is finished running, as well as after all other previously scheduled tasks ([microtasks](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) for promises).

This provides a gap in time that allows other parts of the system within which JS is running, such as the DOM in the browser, to freely operate on parts of the system that they share with the JavaScript engine, knowing JS won't get in their way.

Therefore, in the broadest sense, `fetch` is non-blocking and doesn't block the DOM.

It should be noted that promises represent synchronous code blocks connected via an asynchronous scheduling chain ([the promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)) so technically there are parts of `fetch` that do block the DOM but the overall process can be considered non-blocking for most purposes. See [the answer by mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393379/3928341) for an example.

---

Note: after generators were introduced in ES6, a function stopped being the atomic execution unit in JavaScript. With `yield` and afterwards `await`, JS functions got the ability to break up into multiple async chunks of synchronously executing code.

Answer (score 5):

If by blocking you mean, other scripts and requests cannot run until its request completes: **no**.

If you mean preventing the page load from completing: **yes**, it appears to block.

Here are some tests I made some to compare to demonstrate, requesting a search to google of: *what are dogs?*

`fetch()` which *does* appear to block `window.onload` completion
https://jsfiddle.net/84uopaqb/7/

`XMLHttpRequest`, which *does not* block `window.onload` completion
https://jsfiddle.net/84uopaqb/5/

`$.get()` which also *does not* block `window.onload` completion
https://jsfiddle.net/84uopaqb/1/

If you must use fetch, wrapping the `fetch` request in a `setTimeout` is a workaround to this issue.

**Caveat**: 
I've only tested this in FF Quantum, and not very thoroughly either... but that being said, you should support all major browsers. Even if it's non-blocking in other browsers, its still not a viable solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think what the guy was trying to say is that `fetch` itself is blocking. As in, the time it takes to create an HTTP request and send it is blocking, but your script and UI *won't* be blocked while the request is out and about. Your `then()` callback will also be blocking.

That said, it only takes like a 5th of a millisecond to send your request, it's nothing you need to worry about.

```
> t=performance.now(),fetch('.'),(performance.now()-t)
0.139999999984866
```

Comment: Ok, getting the response is a non-blocking operation, but... what about response.text() or response.json() when is a large text? If I understand you right, could be blocking? This is what my tests say. Do parse a large response.text() in a web worker help to improve ui smoothness?

Comment: @Porkopek I'm not sure actually. `response.text()` and `response.json()` also return Promises so the browser could do those on a different thread if it wanted to, since they're native. Why don't you time it?

Comment: I saw in my program that when resolving a fetch takes a long time, like 5 or 6 seconds, the UI is not so responsive, like, for example, the :hover effect in CSS is not triggered when I move the mouse to a button. I don't know if it is because of the fetch getting the response or the response parsing, so I was wondering why

Comment: @Porkopek You can time it exactly the same way I did. If the elapsed time if `response.json()` is tiny like in my answer, then it's yielding back to the UI thread. Page should responsive unless *maybe* you have a single-core processor and it's consuming all your resources.

Answer (score 0):

You use the fetch API like this:

```
fetch(url)
.then(function(data) {
    // do something with the data fetched
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // error handling
});
```

Yes, [this doesn't block your DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615966/how-to-make-non-blocking-javascript-code). Yes, [your code is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393751/what-does-asynchronous-means-in-ajax).

However, the same applies to oldschool XHR requests with `XMLHttpRequest` :

```
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    // 1. Make an Ajax call to your json file
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var status, data;
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                // 2. Parse the json file once it's been received
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                successHandler && successHandler(data);
            } else {
                errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    // 3. Do something with the content of the file once it's parsed
}, function(status) {
    // Error handling goes here
});
```

The fetch API just provides you a more modern [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based API to do the same thing people used to do with `XMLHttpRequest` and [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213948/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-calls-and-callbacks).

So, both oldschool `XMLHttpRequest` XHR and the fetch API do NOT block your DOM.