# prevent next ajax request wait for previous ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have 2 ajax requests in 1 page. i want to run that 2 ajax requests together at same time.

**First AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "load1.php",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (output) {
        console.log(output);
    }
});
```

**Second AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "load2.php",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (output) {
        console.log(output);
    }
});
```

on `load1.php` i add `sleep(10);` code, so it will delay 10 seconds.

so while i tried to sleep the `first ajax` request, the `second ajax` will wait 10 seconds for the first ajax until its done.
i know it can be done by using `async:false`. but i don't want to use it.
is there another way to prevent it and let the second ajax load without waiting the first ajax?

Comment: Isn't rather async: true what you need?

Comment: i don't want to use async option. @KarloX

Comment: You want the both ajax calls to happen one after the other? or without waiting for response of previous one?

Comment: without waiting of previous one. it means the second ajax can response without waiting for the first one, if the first one response delay @G_S

Comment: AJAX calls do that by default Isnt it?

Comment: yeah because it's asynchronous.  i want to make it synchronous. the best method i use is using `async:false` but it's already deprecated @G_S so i want to try another method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213948/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-calls-and-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

In that case, sleep will not fulfill your requirements. Sleep will delay all of these execution. You can use **setTimeout/setInterval** for your first ajax request. Then your 2nd ajax request will execute independently & first one will execute after 10 seconds.

Something like this

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
    url: "load1.php",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (output) {
     console.log(output);
    }
  });

  }, 10000);
```

Comment: if the connection to mysql is denied or the server is down. it's better to use sleep. because it's the same condition.

Comment: by the way, i don't questioned about sleep or settimeout.

Comment: Issue is - sleep will delay all existing code execution(check http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: so how about if the connection is down? i want the second one can response without the first ajax done.. it's a same case.

Comment: have you tested it using setTimeout? in that case, 2nd one will send response before first one. Because you are delaying first ajax call for certain time. Use this approach & check your browser's network tab, hope it will be clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

from @G_S statement. it was true that ajax is asynchronous by default. when we use `async:false` then ajax will become synchronous. i have found my problem that in my php files there was session_start in every files. then when I put `sleep` code in one of files, it will become session lock. it means that the ajax will wait the session start again to load if there were `sleep` code..