# How do I know to which 'callback function' function refers to

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I don't understand the use of the general word callback. I am investigating a big JS code and in the same class I have these two functions, both using callback but I can't get which function will be called back...I guess I'm missing a basic knowledge about callbacks.. can someone explain please..

My example is general, I need to understand the idea of using callback **what will be the next step**, my code works I just need to understand it...

```
getNames(callback: (Names: name[]) => void, Name:string) {        
        Names = ['david','elton','eliza']
            callback(Names);
        });
    } 
    getFood(callback: (Foods : Food []) => void, Food:string) {        
        Foods = ['egg','bacon','chicken']
            callback(Foods);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You could start at: [How to explain callbacks in plain english?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o#answer-9644980)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden thanks but I already red it, didn't help me much :/

Comment: `callback` in these examples is the parameter name

Comment: @phuzi it doesn't a refer to a function ?

Comment: It doesn't help that this is invalid code, as the `{}` braces and `()` brackets don't match.

Comment: when you call `getNames` you'll pass it a function that will act as a callback. `callback` is an arbitrary name for the parameter.

Comment: @lonesomeday this code is just for example it dosen't have to work.. I just need to understand the Idea I dont know what is the next step where is the callback function

Comment: Yes it refers to the function that you'll pass in the arguments of the `getNames` or `getFood` functions. (e.g:  you have a function called `yourfunction()` if you do `getNames(yourfunction,'blabla')`  the argument `yourfunction`will be your callback.

Comment: @SteevePitis ok, so if I get it right - **callback: (Names: name[]) => void** means that getNames function accept a callback function as an argument and that callback function needs to have an array of Names as an argument and to be void function.

Comment: Yes it's right ;)

Comment: @SteevePitis Thank you!