# Anti-pattern name for firing events on an object member supplied at instantiation?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

An object requires it be instantiated with an object upon which it can call a method to register than an event has occurred — rather than the instantiating code listening for events.

Is this an anti-pattern? If so, does it have a name?

Is there a reason to code this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an object-to-be-called into a constructor is usually used for the "constructor injection" type of dependency injection.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection

When used in that way it's an excellent pattern...

But if the object being passed in is really an event listener, then it becomes a bad idea.  Injecting an event listener is not "dependency injection", because an object doesn't *depend* on its event listeners, and so it shouldn't require any in its constructor.  It would also be very bad form to restrict an event-generating object such that it could have only one listener.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an anti-pattern?

No

> does it have a name?

Yes: [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

> Is there a reason to code this way?

Certainly, see: [How to explain callbacks in plain english?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o)

Note that a constructor is a method as well. There's nothing inherently different about passing a callback to a constructor versus any other method.

Comment: Not a callback — object A is passed to B, B has to call a specific method to fire an event on A. Tight coupling — bad. B could emit an event which A listens for — de-coupled, good.

Comment: Still a callback. Using an object to pass the function doesn't change the nature of the relationship. In object-oriented languages without first-class functions, passing an object may be the only way to pass a callback function. Decoupling can still be achieved by utilizing something akin to a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) (Java example).

Comment: Oh — are you suggesting to use a callback? Or are you suggesting the pattern the Q describes *is* a callback...?

Comment: I'm suggesting the latter: an object can _be_ a callback. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#Implementation), "_In object-oriented programming languages without function-valued arguments, such as in Java before its 8 version, callbacks can be simulated by passing an instance of an abstract class or interface..._"