# How are callbacks coded in Javascript, behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

How does a function know that something is a callback; something that needs to be executed once certain prior I/O has completed. How does it know that it shouldn't execute right away? Is it defined in a function in a (standardized) way?

As far as I know the 'callback' keyword that is often used in an argument is just common practise, but does not automatically let the function interpret the argument as something that should start once certain I/O has completed.

Taking the below example, I have two questions (taken from https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee):

```
const request = require(‘request’);
function handleResponse(error, response, body){
    if(error){
        // Handle error.
    }
    else {
        // Successful, do something with the result.
    }
}
request('https://www.somepage.com', handleResponse);
```

1. What does the structure of the 'require' function look like so that it knows that argument 2 (handleResponse in this case) should be executed once the request has completed? I guess this gets down to the same question that I asked above.
2. Can functions be asynchronous even without the async keyword in the function? If yes, how does the browser know it's an asynchronous function?

Comment: [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function), [How to explain callbacks in plain english? How are they different from calling one function from another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o)

Comment: The way I understood it is that browser will keep executing and then return back to the function once it has finished e.g. AJAX query. How can I have the browser stop and wait for query execution, not doing anything until that has succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume you meant to ask about the `request` function. Most asynchronous functions call other asynchronous functions to do some work, and then call the callback. You can think of it as a chain of functions and callbacks. This is what the `request` function does. Of course, at least the last function needs to be truly asynchronous, and usually that is a function exported by one of the node built-in modules (`fs`, `http`, ...). It may also be exported by a native module, or using the `worker_threads` module in more recent node versions.
2. The `async` keyword isn't required for a function to be asynchronous. Marking a function as `async` lets the function use the `await` syntax and makes the function return a Promise implicitly.

To better understand how asynchronous code works, you should take a look at how the  [node event loop](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) works

Note that I assumed a Node.js environment, because you used `require`, but most of what I said applies to the browser as well: there is a chain of asynchronous functions, and the last one will call one of the built-in functions (for instance `XMLHttpRequest`). The browser environment uses an event loop too, and `async/await` work in the same way