# How passing a function as argument is working here?

Tags: javascript, callback

```js
var years = [1990, 1965, 1937];
     
  function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
    var arrRes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
    }
    return arrRes;
  }

  function calculateAge(el) {
    return 2017 - el;
  }

  var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);
  console.log(ages);
```

How this code is working, I am new to javascript can anyone break it down and make it simple for me.

Comment: what is the part, you don't understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain callbacks in plain english? How are they different from calling one function from another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652434/4642212). Also see [How are callbacks coded in Javascript, behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58462670/4642212).

Comment: how fn related to calculateAge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrayCalc` function takes two parameters:

1. `arr` - Array you want to do calculation on
2. `fn` - This is another function representing the calculation you want to do on elements of the `arr`. It is ussualy refered to as `callback function`

`callback function` is function that you send as a argument to another function. In your case main function is `arrayCalc` and `callback function` is `calculateAge`

Main function ussually invokes(uses) callback function on the other parameter. That would be array `years` in your example.

So your `main function` goes trought elements of you array and invokes `callback funcion` with that element as a argument and save result to the new array that is then returned from your 'main function'

---

I will try to make it more clear by rewording your example:

```
function arrayCalc(parameterArray, parameterCallbackFunction) {
  // create new array for results of calling callback
  var newArray = [];
  // goes trough the array
  for (var indexOfElement = 0; indexOfElement < parameterArray.length; indexOfElement++) {
   // this is callbackFunction invocation with element of array as argument: parameterCallbackFunction(parameterArray[indexOfElement])
   // and we put the resul to the newArray by push method
   newArray.push(parameterCallbackFunction(parameterArray[indexOfElement]));
  }
  // at the end we return newArray filled with results of calling callbackFunction on array   
  return newArray;
}

// this is array we want to change using callbackFunction
var argumentArray = [1990, 1965, 1937];

// this is our callback function  
function argumentCallbackFunction(elementFromArray) {
  return 2017 - elementFromArray;
}

// this is invocation of our main function
// first parameter is array and second is our callback function
var ages = arrayCalc(argumentArray, argumentCallbackFunction);
console.log(ages);
```

You can create many more callback function and use them in `arrayCalc`

```
// this is second callbackFunction
function addTenToYear(elementFromArray) {
  return elementFromArray + 10;
}

// invocation arrayCalc with second callback function
var agesAfterAddition = arrayCalc(originalArray, addTenToYear);
console.log(agesAfterAddition); // [2000, 1975, 1947]


// this is third callbackFunction
function substractTenFromYear(elementFromArray) {
  return elementFromArray - 10;
}

// invocation arrayCalc with third callback function
var agesAfterSubstraction = arrayCalc(originalArray, substractTenFromYear);
console.log(agesAfterSubstraction); // [1980, 1955, 1927]
```

---

Something like this is going on in your code:

```
var originalArray = [1990, 1965, 1937]
var newArray = []
newArray.push( callbackFunction(1990) ) // 2017 - 1990 = 27
console.log(newArray) // [27]
newArray.push( callbackFunction(1965) ) // 2017 - 1965 = 52
console.log(newArray) // [27, 52]
newArray.push( callbackFunction(1937) ) // 2017 - 1937 = 80
console.log(newArray) // [27, 52, 80]
```

Comment: Oh, So here fn is not actually the callback function, it is just referring to another function that is calculateAge??

Comment: @DevenderSharma `fn` is representation of callBack function you put in as parameter. You can create many many callBack functions and then pas them to `arrayCalc` and do different calculations. You can  do one when you add years to elements in array and one where you subtract from year

Comment: function outer() {
  return function(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
  }
}
 
var devender = outer();
devender('rahul');

here how the variable can be a function in the last line, it is working but How?

Answer (score 0):

Function are first-class objects in JavaScript. So, like objects, other functions can also be passed as an argument to higher-order functions. A callback function is just called back at a later time. In this case `arrayCalc` is a higher-order function and `fn` is a callback function. `fn` expects an argument. The first parameter of the higher-order function is passed as an argument to the callback function.