# Callback Function is not working in JavaScript example

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's wrong in the following `callback function example`? I am passing some parameters and in the end, I am passing a function that must `automatically` run when the other tasks are done. So, why am I getting an error?

**Expectation:**

I expected 2 console.logs. First giving output of `a, b, a+b` and second console printing `hello`.

**Example:**

```js
function alpha(a, b, ()=>{
  console.log("hello");
}){
  console.log(a, b, a+b);
}
alpha(5, 10);
```

Comment: _"I am passing a function..."_ - No you're "defining" a function with 2 parameters and an anonymous function without a parameter - which is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Andreas - correct it with code? will be helpful!

Comment: There's already an answer (+ [How to explain callbacks in plain english? How are they different from calling one function from another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o))

Comment: @Andreas - this means even if I can pass 3 functions as parameters and then I call all 3 one after another in parent function, so will this mean this function has 3 callback functions?

Comment: It has three parameters that, if you pass actual functions, would be called _"one after another"_. Every function you pass as argument for one of the parameters would be a "callback". That setup would be quite unusual, normally there is only one "callback".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
function alpha(a, b, fn) {
    console.log(a, b, a + b);
    fn();
}
alpha(5, 10, () => {
    console.log("hello");
});

// or defined by default
function alpha2(a, b, fn = () => {
    console.log("hello");
}) {
    console.log(a, b, a + b);
    fn();
}
alpha2(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this, with passing parameters to callback function:

```js
function alpha(a, b, f = (a,b) => a+b) {
    return f(a,b);
}

const multiply = (a,b) => a*b
console.log(alpha(5, 10));
console.log(alpha(5, 10, multiply));
```