# JQuery page loading dynamically

Tags: jquery

i search for jquery page load.

I always face that people use  something like that

```
jQuery("#popup").fadeIn(4000); //function to redirect the page after few seconds
                            window.location.replace("http://"+a_href);  
                        }, 3000)
```

They sets timeout 3000 .However, there is a possibilty that the page could not be loadded after 3 sec.

Is there a way to do this dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to predict whether 3 seconds is long enough, you can simply use a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) so that the element isn't faded back in until it has loaded.

Also, `window.location.replace()` won't load the content into the popup, it'll change the whole web page to this new location. Instead you should use [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (`$.load()`).

Therefore you don't need the fade animation to last for 3 seconds, you can have it animate as long/short as you like. In my example I've reduced this to 0.3 seconds.

Use the following instead:

```
var $popup = $("#popup");
$popup.fadeOut(300, function(){
   $popup.load("http://"+a_href, function(){
       $popup.fadeIn(300);
   });   
});
```

Comment: but after 300, my page is not loaded. What i want is that it finishes after page is load

Comment: thank you so is there a specific element to set popup id ? Otherwise, can i use popup element for body id