# Why are callback functions called that?

Tags: objective-c, callback, terminology

The reason for the name 'callback' eludes me. What does that term mean?

Comment: Because it's what functions... call back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Callback functions in C/C++/C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183847/callback-functions-in-c-c-c)

Comment: Also: [What is a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 4):

Because it provides a mechanism for a library to call back into your code.

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks are called that because when you give something a callback, you enable it to "call back" into your code at a later time.