# need to reload mainActivity controller on click of button located in customized listview

Tags: android, android-listview

To make my question more understandable let me start with an image of my view.

[image]

I have an xml file named Menu, that has customized list view in it. I have created another xmlview named MenuCell as below.
[image]

Now tapping on add button I'm adding Item to the cart. which is working perfectly fine except not updating value of a cart (top right corner) on click event. But If I navigate to different view and come back to this view at this point I'm getting number of items added in the cart reflected properly. So How Can I reload my controllerview when I tap in my arradepter view's ImageButton.

this is my adapter code

```
holder.imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                addItem(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

void addItem(int position) {

        count++;
        }
```

Where count is item added count.

If anyone can tell How am I able to reflect this count of my arrayadpter class to my other controller class that holds actual list view.

Any Help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Send the reference of your controller to your list adapter class. In the controller I guess you have a method that computes some data and after that call update the view that holds cart data summary. Just make sure that update is on UI thread.

Comment: Hi gunar thanks for your response but can u please explain it in bit detail.

Comment: the controller is a model class or is it a simple view? (`TextView`?)

Comment: ok, where does it live? how is it related to your root activity or the view where you hold the cart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback feature to get notified to your activity , hence add button is part of list component so you can update your list view.

Here are few links for understanding of call back using interface

```
http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/10/understanding-callbacks-with-java.html


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577695/what-is-a-call-back-interface-in-java
```

Answer (score 0):

After :
      `notifyDataSetChanged();`
just add:
`YourList.invalidateViews();

YourList.scrollBy(0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Your List is not refreshing at the instant because you have to refresh data of your adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Suppose You have the data in an array which is visible in textview.Then In your function addItem add the data into ur array and then call  notifyDataSetChanged();
This will immediately tell the list view that watever data it is containing is changed so time to refresh.

If you can paste more of ur adapter code i can be helpful