# Why doesn't my div fade out

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the Jquery.UI library, the issue is, the example given at jqueryui.com is when you pass the effect type, where I want to load a fade out

The JSFiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/L3pMG/2/

My code

```
<div id="effect">
    <h3>Hide</h3>
    <p>Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.</p>
</div>

<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
         $( "#effect" ).hide( "blind", 1000, callback );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Because `callback` is not defined. That's why you get an error and the code can't be run. See the [edited jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3pMG/3/).

Comment: @IonicăBizău please move to answer so I can mark it as such

Comment: Posted. Next time see the browser errors before posting a question like this. :-)

Comment: ... Because I was doing everything in fiddle, I didn't even consider opening up firebug... Ooops.

Comment: You can check the errors opening the dev tools even your application is in the jsfiddle. Anyway, I was happy to help you. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `callback` is not defined. That's why you get an error and the code can't be run.

You can simply remove it or define the `callback` function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#effect" ).hide( "blind", 1000);
});
```

or

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var callback = function () { console.log("foo"); }
   $( "#effect" ).hide( "blind", 1000, callback);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L3pMG/3/)

---

To learn what the `callback`s are, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/824234/1420197).

Using `hide()` jQuery method you can pass a function as last parameter. See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

> `complete`
>
> Type: `Function()`
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 4):

Your only problem is that `callback` is not defined, take away that and it works fine.

Comment: this is +1 but, the comment answered first although you are right.

Comment: I know, that's why I upped the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly the entirety of your code, you have to wrap the script in `<script>` tags before it will do anything.

It also seems to be breaking on "callback" so try removing that argument.

```
<div id="effect">
    <h3>Hide</h3>
    <p>Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.</p>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#effect" ).hide( "blind", 1000 );
});
</script>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/L3pMG/5/