# what calls startElement method when parsing xml with java

Tags: java, android, xml

I was going through [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94) and I noticed that startElement method is called twice but i do not see any method call for this... it seems to be happening automatically... can you explain to me how this method is called ?

Comment: it might be a callback method

Answer (score 1):

The callback method is called by the **Parser Object** when it reaches the start of an object. 
For example, to parse an xml file using an SAX parser you will have :

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse(new File(sourceFile), this);
```

where "this" refers to the current class that implements the interface **ContentHandler**. We override the callback methods such as **startElement**, and they will be called when your saxParser reads through certain events.

also please refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) about callback functions if interested.

Answer (score 0):

`startElement` is started when new tag occurs, and when you close this tag `endElement` is called. So if you have something like this:

```
<jobs>
      <job>
          <id>4</id>
          ...
          ...
    </job>
</jobs>
```

first xml parser opens `jobs` tag and then `job`. When he finish, he calls first `job` and then `jobs`

Comment: is it called automatically ?

Comment: what part of the code calls it.. can you provide more details just exactly how it is called ?