# Run javascript function after excecution of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function like in some of sub pages,

```
function fuct(){

....
somecode inside
}
```

What I want to do is execute another function called function `anotherfunction` after successful execution of function `funct` which is in main html page. And I dont want to call `anotherfunction` in body of fuct.

Can I do something like,

on.succss of funct call anotherfunction

Comment: It sounds a lot like you want promises - check out https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: simply when you call first function, call another function after just that..

Comment: What is in your first function?  If it's all synchronous (e.g. no networking), then you can just call your second function right after you call your first: `a();  b();`.  If your first function has asynchronous operations in it, then you will have to be more specific about what it has in it.  Far too little information disclosed here to do anything more than make wild guesses.

Comment: If your first function has a return value, you can check the return value after it finishes and decide what to do next based on that.  Nothing more to say without you disclosing more about the real problem you're trying to solve with more real code.

Answer (score 3):

The missing keyword is [*callback*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/824234/1420197).

You can have something like this:

```
function funct(callback) {
   // do something
   callback(a, b, c, ..., n);
}

function anotherFunction(a, b, c, ..., n) {
   // do something
}

funct(anotherFunction);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q0ueywa0/)

---

Another way is using promises:

```
function func() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    // do something
    deferred.resolve(position);


    // return promise so that outside code cannot reject/resolve the deferred
    return deferred.promise();
};

funct().then(anotherFunction);
```

Comment: You're just wild guessing here.  The OP hasn't said anything about what's in the first function.

Comment: @jfriend00 (S)He will ask for more information if it's needed. :-)

Comment: Still a wild guess.  The OP's question is completely unclear (they don't mention anything about asynchronous operations which you are trying to solve for) and should be downvoted and then closed if they don't clarify shortly.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, true.

Answer (score 3):

do something like

```
function function1()
{
    //if succeeds
    return true;
}
```

then where you need

```
if (function1()) {
    //call another function
}
```

Comment: Why do this?  What if `function1()` doesn't return anything.  This seems like another wild guess and not a general answer.

Comment: Yeah, which means it isn't a general purpose answer.  The fact is that the OP's question is not clear at all so all you can do is guess or explain all possible answers given the uncertainty in the question.

Comment: yes, somewhat it is. we can just suggest him how can he do this.