# How can I fix this local data issue? (Chrome extension, Javascript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to save local data in a chrome extension, but it's not working.  The 'getData' function keeps returning undefined.  What am I doing wrong?  Yes, I do have 'storage' under my permissions in the manifest.

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local

var getData = function(key) {
    var give;
    storage.get(null, function(objects) {
        $.each(objects, function(index, value) {
            if (index == key) { 
                give = value
                console.log(value) //OUTPUT: Hello!
            }
        })
    })
    return give
}

storage.set({"test" : "Hello!"})
console.log(getData("test")) //OUTPUT: undefined
```

Comment: So I just learned that the storage API is asynchronous... How can I modify my function to wait for the data, then return it?

Comment: You can't make your code wait for  an asynchronous operation. You must chain your calls via callbacks.

Comment: Does anyone know a canonical question for this? To close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback function, this way:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;

var getData = function(key, callback) {
    storage.get(null, function(objects) {
        $.each(objects, function(index, value) {
            if (index == key) { 
                callback(null, value);
            }
        });
    });
};

storage.set({"test" : "Hello!"});
getData("test", function (err, data) { // err will be null
    console.log(data); // "Hello!"
});
```

[What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/824234/1420197)