# How to add an instance of a model to an instance of another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The model Patient `belongs_to` FeedList, which `has_many` patients. I'm attempting, upon the creation of a new FeedList I want to add all patients that are currently in the DB to the FeedList. I'm currently attempting to do it within `create` of `feed_lists_controller.rb`.

```
def create
    @feed_list = FeedList.new(feed_list_params)

    Patients.all.each do |p|
      @feed_list.patients << p
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feed_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @feed_list, notice: 'Feed list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @feed_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @feed_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

however, it doesn't seem to be registering when I create a new FeedList

```
[8] pry(main)> FeedList.create
=> #<FeedList:0xbaf7bdd0
 id: 3,
 created_at: Sun, 29 Nov 2015 01:11:54 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 29 Nov 2015 01:11:54 UTC +00:00,
 date: nil,
 integer: nil>
[9] pry(main)> FeedList.last.patients
=> #<Patient::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x-2284f570>
```

FeedList.rb:

```
class FeedList < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :patients

after_create :add_patients
  private
    def add_patients
      ::Patients.all.each do |p|
        self.patients << p
      end
    end

end
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: pls see edit, it doesnt seem to be working @jason

Comment: The create action isn't a callback that gets invoked every time you create an instance of a model, it's a controller action that runs whenever a route is visited that is tied to it. At least, that's how it's usually set up. Where is this create function?

Comment: it's in the `feed_lists_controller.rb` file

Comment: I'm guessing that you're editing someone else's code, right? That's a normal controller `create` action that you're editing. That action will be called whenever a client (or you) visits the route that is associated with it. Run `rake routes` from a terminal window to see what `URI Pattern` is associated with the `Controller#Action` `feed_lists#create`. If you visit that page and create a new `FeedList` using the form there, it will run your code.

Comment: It's code that I generated with `rails g scaffold`. It's a group project that we're working on - we have other functional `create` actions - I guess I just didn't fully understand (or still don't understand) exactly how the controller functions

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#what-does-a-controller-do-questionmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in your FeedList model file:

```
after_create :add_patients

  private
    def add_patients
      Patient.all.each do |p|
        self.patients << p
      end
    end
```

As Jason mentioned above "create action [that is in your controller] isn't a callback that gets invoked every time you create an instance of a model". See [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) for information on what is a callback. The `after_create` callback essentially says to invoke `add_patients` right after you call `FeedList.create`

Comment: thank you, i'll try that now. Can you explain to a novice what a "callback" is and why you have to put`after_create :add_patients` at the top?

Comment: A callback is a generic programming term for a function that runs when your code finishes doing something, like reading a file, opening a video stream, or creating a database record.

Comment: Now I'm getting
`NameError: uninitialized constant FeedList::Patients`

How do I initialize it within the FeedList model?

Comment: Hmm what does your FeedList model class look like? A quick fix might be `::Patients.all.each` but I would need to see the file.

Comment: Indent the `after_create` to the same level as `private`. But I don't see any issues there. What is the name of the file for your Patients model along with your FeedList?

Comment: its just `patient.rb`

Comment: Try `Patient` instead of `Patients`.

Comment: Lol my bad there :p Nice catch @Jason

Comment: Until he gave the file name, I assumed he had named his model `Patients`.

Comment: ok! out of the fire into the frying pan..
`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute "feed_list_id"`

Comment: You might want to open a new question. You would probably want to give which line the error comes from and the surrounding lines. It also might be worth taking a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MissingAttributeError.html

Comment: very big thanks for all the help: problem was solved with a simple `db:migrate` by adding `feed_list_id` to `patient`. It seems to me that using a model for feed list is hardly best practice but it will work!