# Can't get data body use nodejs

Tags: node.js, request

Function

```
function getpage(link, callback){
  var options = {
     method: 'GET',
     uri: link,
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93:").toString('base64')
     }
  };
  request(options, function (err, response, body) {
     callback(body);
  });
}
```

Code working when:

```
getpage('https://docs.google.com/feeds/get_video_info?formats=ios&mobile=true&docid=0BxG6kVC7OXgrQ1V6bDVsVmJMZFU', console.log);
```

But not working when

```
var text = getpage(link, console.log);
console.log(text);
```

How do I fix it? I want data to return the same. I want to use the data in other function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback function.

```
getpage(link, function(data){
  var text = data;
  console.log(text);

  // Do something with your text here
});
```

Read more about callbacks and asynchronous call [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function).