# Is there a pattern where the client is both the Subscriber and the Publisher

Tags: design-patterns

First off, i am using HTML5 Websockets connected to a Jetty Server for communication.

All clients are publishers and subscribers. A client can publish data to a Topic and sometimes only that client will receive an update, other times everyone who is subscribed will receive a notification including the publisher.

Comment: As long as you subscribe to whatever you is published, why couldn't  the same computer be both?

Comment: As far as i understand it.  
Observer has the following methods  
  
+ attach(Observer observer)  
+ detech(Observer observer)  
+ notifyAll()  
  
My current solution is to send the observer as an argument for the publish(Observer observer) method, so that i can reply directly to that observer without notifying everyone, however i am worried that this solution breaks the purpose of the pattern.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a [callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function).

Comment: The Observer pattern is the same as publish and subscribe and is commonly used in multi threaded environments, not just distributed systems