# Issue when calling multiple function in a single method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to bind dropdown and select user by id. so I have two methods like (getting users) and (select users) when I am calling select user method so it's calling but not selecting any dropdown value.

```
function getUsers() {
try {

    objReqUser.PageIndex = 1;
    objReqUser.PageSize = 2000;
    objReqUser.TotalPageCount = 0;
    objReqUser.User.OpType = 2;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: APIUrl + 'api/GetUsers?JSONStringData=' + JSON.stringify(objReqUser),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            objResUser = data;

            if (objResUser != null && parseInt(objResUser.ID) > 0) {
                var ddl = $("[id*=ddlDeliveryBoy]");
                ddl.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Delivery Boy</option>');
                $.each(objResUser.User, function () {
                    ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(this.ID).html(this.UniqueName));
                });
            }
            else {

                if (objResUser != null)
                    messageProvider(objResUser.ID, objResUser.Msg);
                else
                    messageProvider(0, "There is an error !");
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            messageProvider(0, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    messageProvider(0, err.message);
}
```

}

and Select User Method

```
function selectUser(ID) {

try {
    getUsers()

    $('#ddlDeliveryBoy').val(1);

}
catch (err) {
    messageProvider(0, err.message);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what is happening is when you do $.ajax, it returns you a callback which is asynchronous. In your method, you wrote two synchronous statements

`statement1 -> sync
statement2 -> sync`

normally they would run synchronously, but over here since u used $.ajax

`statement1 ->async
statement2 -> sync`

so, to handle the async behaviour of statement1 and meet the requirement of calling statement2 after statement1 has done it's $.ajax. we pass a callback.

To read more about callbacks: [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

The first method has a callback inside, and your seconds statement is sync. changing the code to:

```
function callback() {
 $('#ddlDeliveryBoy').val(1);
}

getUsers(callback);

function getUsers(callback) {
try {

    objReqUser.PageIndex = 1;
    objReqUser.PageSize = 2000;
    objReqUser.TotalPageCount = 0;
    objReqUser.User.OpType = 2;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: APIUrl + 'api/GetUsers?JSONStringData=' + JSON.stringify(objReqUser),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            objResUser = data;

            if (objResUser != null && parseInt(objResUser.ID) > 0) {
                var ddl = $("[id*=ddlDeliveryBoy]");
                ddl.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Delivery Boy</option>');
                $.each(objResUser.User, function () {
                    ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(this.ID).html(this.UniqueName));
                });
            }
            else {

                if (objResUser != null)
                    messageProvider(objResUser.ID, objResUser.Msg);
                else
                    messageProvider(0, "There is an error !");
            }

            callback();

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            messageProvider(0, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    messageProvider(0, err.message);
}
```

Comment: Good one but I didn't get this one please describe me once again

Comment: Ok, I got it. but my condition is I have an empty dropdown and I am binding data from ajax as you look. Then I am using the select method because in select method I have dropdown value ID then I am doing called get user method then select a dropdown value by given ID...

Comment: so, what is the missing piece here?

Comment: I didn't get you. Maybe nothing

Comment: ok, if there is any part you would like explained further, let me know

Comment: sorry, buddy I haven't any other part of this Page. I'm using only two methods for selecting drop down and then that this issue occurs.