# Capture photos from video after specific time in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
var video;
var snapshots = [];
var readyCheck = false;
var button;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 600);
    background(0);
    video = createCapture(VIDEO, ready);
    video.size(200, 150);
}

function ready() {
    readyCheck = true;
    console.log('work');
}

function draw() {
    var w = 200;
    var h = 150;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    if (readyCheck) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // use setTimeout() to wait for 2 seconds
            setTimeout(function() {
                snapshots[i] = video.get();
                image(snapshots[i],x, y);
                x += w;
                if (x >= width) {
                    x = 0;
                    y += h;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

my purpose is taking pictures from the webcam after specific time. So I use the `setTimeout()` in JS. I expect pictures will appear on the canvas every 2 seconds in a row.

when entering the for part, the code will wait 2 seconds and capture the image from webcam and display it.

but my situation is that all the picture appear on the canvas at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a step back and understand how the `draw()` function and the `setTimeout()` functions work.

- The `draw()` function is automatically called 60 times per second. You can adjust this by calling the `frameRate()` function or the `noLoop()` function. More info is available in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).
- The `setTimeout()` function sets up a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) that is automatically called after some duration, in your case 2 seconds.

So, what your code is doing is setting up 100 callback functions that will  all fire in 2 seconds- and it's doing this 60 times per second! So in 1 second, you'll have 6000 functions that will start firing 2 seconds later! This is almost definitely not what you want.

P5.js already has its own timing mechanism in the `draw()` function that's called 60 times per second, so it seems a little weird to use the `setTimeout()` function inside P5.js code. Instead, you should probably set up your own timing using the `frameCount` variable or the `millis()` function.

Here's an example that shows a random color every second:

```js
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(200, 200);
} 

function draw() { 
  if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
   background(random(256), random(256), random(256));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

This code uses the `frameCount` variable and the `%` [modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.100).aspx) to check whether 60 frames have passed, and if so, it sets the background to a random color. You'll want to do something similar.

Like I said above, more info about all of this can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps a lot !!!
But my confusion still exists.
my thought is that when entering the for loop, the `setTimeout()` is triggered, then wait for 2 seconds, drawing the pictures and entering another next step in the for loop, and waiting for 2 seconds, then next pictures. on and on.
why you said it will be all triggered at the same time?

thanks you~

Comment: @SoulerTsai Please read the documentation on the `setTimeout()` function, as it doesn't work at all like what you're describing.

Comment: Ok, I know what I misunderstood.
At first I thought `setTimeout()` is more like delay, so I think it will some kind of "waiting".
But I am wrong in the end.