# javascript callback, how does it work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a callback function, and i can't find a solution to pass an argument in this callback ..

```
var chrome = {
  enterprise: {
    deviceAttributes: {
      getDirectoryDeviceId: function() {
        return "test";
      }
    }
  }
};

chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId(function(deviceid) {
  alert(deviceid);
});
```

How can the deviceid in the callback function be "xxx" ?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `getDirectoryDeviceId` doesn't accept an argument, so the argument you're passing in is ignored.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  There is no async code here.

Comment: `How can the deviceid in the callback function be "xxx" ?` i mean... the more important question is why is the callback function being called for you to know the deviceid is xxx?

Comment: The snippet you posted wont call the callback. Try posting a relevant code so that we can say why its alerting xxx

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function

Comment: @karthick that isn't how i interpreted the question.  I don't think he's saying it's alerting `xxx`.  I think he's asking how to set the `deviceid` in the callback to a specific value.  "How can I make it be 'xxx'?"

Comment: May be useful: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a function into `getDirectoryDeviceId` when you call it...but not calling that function or accepting it as an argument

Try:

```js
var chrome = {
  enterprise: {
    deviceAttributes: {
      getDirectoryDeviceId: function(callback) {
                                   // ^^ function you already pass in when you call method

        // call the callback you pass in below
        callback("test");
      }
    }
  }
};
// nothing changed here
chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId(function(deviceid) {
  alert(deviceid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId` is being assigned a function that takes no arguments, so you'd need to set one up there.

Then, when you call `getDirectoryDeviceId` the function that you pass can be executed by appending `()` to the argument.

Lastly, if you want to be able to pass an argument that the callback will use, you need to set up a second argument in the function.

```js
var chrome = {
   enterprise: {
    deviceAttributes: {
      getDirectoryDeviceId : function(callback, data){
        callback(data);
      }
    }
  }
};


chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId(function (deviceid){
  alert(deviceid);
}, "TEST!");  // <-- Second argument is the data that will be used by the callback
```