# Callback instead of setTimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, callback, prepend

I have the following working code:

```
// Get photos from file and load first initial photo
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "photos_gps.json",
    success: initialPhoto,
    error: handleError
});

function initialPhoto(data){

    console.log(data);

    var img_tag = "<img id=" + '"photoBox" src=' + "'photos/" + data[0].Filename + "' />";

    console.log("Img_tag: " + img_tag); 
    $('#mainBox').prepend(img_tag); 
    photos = data;

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($('#photoBox').height());
        console.log($('#photoBox').width());
    }, 1000);
}
```

First I'm loading a file which contains information about images. 
After succes I choose the first image and prepend this to the DOM element. When I log the width and height of the image without the setTimeOut function the values will be both 0 and with setTimeOut function 3648 and 5472.

I want to get rid of the setTimeOut function so I've tried the following callback function:

```
$('#mainBox').prepend(img_tag, function() {
    console.log($('#photoBox').height());
    console.log($('#photoBox').width());
});
```

This results into the following text added below the image:

> function() { console.log($('#photoBox').height()); 
>   console.log($('#photoBox').width()); }

Looks like I don't understand callbacks yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While jQuery's `.prepend` method does take a callback function, that callback function needs to:

> returns an HTML string, DOM element(s), text node(s), or jQuery object to insert at the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements

The reason the `height` and `width` of your `img` element is initially `0` is that the image hasn't loaded yet, and the reason the deferred execution with `.setTimeout` works is that your image loads before the deferred execution kicks in.

To accomplish this without `.setTimeout`, add an event listener for the image's `load` event:

```
function initialPhoto(data) {
    console.log(data);

    var img_tag = $('<img />', {
        id: 'photoBox',
        src: 'photos/' + data[0].Filename,
    }).on('load', function (e) {
        console.log($('#photoBox').height());
        console.log($('#photoBox').width());
    });

    console.log("Img_tag: " + img_tag); 
    $('#mainBox').prepend(img_tag); 
    photos = data;
}
```

Also, [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) is a good place to learn more about callback functions.

Comment: thanks your answer it works. When I look throught the available events I would expect that the .ready event should also work, but this isn't the case

Comment: @ÖmerSoy Glad I could help. To my knowledge, the `ready` "event" is a jQuery construction and only happens once (when the DOMContent is loaded and ready).  You may be able to find other useful events for the `img` elements at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement