# Confusion about callback concept in javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, express

I'm a JavaScript developer and for server side I always do Node/Express. Now I'm learning to use Laravel but I'm running some confusions about `callback` concept.

For exemple: In Express when I do `app.get('/myroute', function(req, res){...})` , the `function(req, res)` part is callback that will run after the serve receives the `get` request. In Laravel I have have something similar when using the routing system like when I do `Route::get('/myroute', function(){...})` - I understand that the static method `get` of the `Route` class is executed but the `function(){...}` at the second parameter. So is that function also called "callback" like it the case for JavaScript? Is the event concept the same for the 2 programming languages?

Comment: Sure. You can call it a callback. PHP doesn't have events as is. To be able to use events, you need to have a library (or write your own) that handles that. Then it's up to the implementation to decide how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function in the `Route::get('/myroute',function(){...})` is indeed a callback. PHP also calls those [callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

The `event` concept may or may not be used on either language. It's all about the context of each situation. This is true because callbacks can be used with our without the need of having an event.

Answer (score 0):

Callback concept is the same in all programming language. Executing a function a get the return response as a parameter in your callback. [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)