# How to wait for data before next execution in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, server

How to wait for data before run the next execution in node.js. For example, I have 3 parts need to be executed. Collect data from job table, collect data from vehicle table then run my jar file. So the current output of console is `0->1->3->5->7->2->4->6`. How to make it like `0->1->3->2->4->5->6->7` . I want to wait for data from first and second query then run the jar file.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //console.log("pending data");

    console.log("0");

    var date = req.param('date');
    var joblist;
    var vehiclelist;

    console.log("1");

    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM job WHERE date = ?',[date] , function (error, results, fields) {
        console.log("2");
        if (error) throw error;
        joblist = JSON.stringify(results);
    });

    console.log("3");

    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM vehicle ' , function (error, results, fields) {
        console.log("4");
        if (error) throw error;
        vehiclelist = JSON.stringify(results);
    });

    console.log("5");

    var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('java -jar /home/java/testinput.jar',
  function (error, stdout, stderr){
    //console.log('stdout: ' + JSON.stringify(stdout));
    //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    console.log("6");
    res.send(joblist+"  "+stderr);
    if(error !== null){
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
console.log("7");

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the following:

```
function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log("2");
    if (error) throw error;
    joblist = JSON.stringify(results);
}
```

is a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) function. You're passing that function in your `query()` call, and telling it to execute the function when it's finished executing the query. As soon as your code has *requested* that query (not executed it), it immediately goes on to execute the next code.

In earlier days, the solution to this would be to define all later actions *inside that callback function*, as roughly such:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //console.log("pending data");

    console.log("0");

    var date = req.param('date');
    var joblist;
    var vehiclelist;

    console.log("1");

    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM job WHERE date = ?',[date] , function (error, results, fields) {
        console.log("2");
        if (error) throw error;
        joblist = JSON.stringify(results);

        console.log("3");

        res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM vehicle ' , function (error, results, fields) {
            console.log("4");
            if (error) throw error;
            vehiclelist = JSON.stringify(results);

            console.log("5");

            // etc

            res.send('blah')
        });

    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Modern JS now has promises, and async/await, which are generally accepted as nicer replacements for callbacks in asynchronous code: https://javascript.info/async-await

Quick snippet as per follow-up comment: (It's not fully working code, just an example of the concepts)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    //console.log("pending data");

    console.log("0");

    var date = req.param('date');
    var joblist;
    var vehiclelist;

    console.log("1");

    var promises = [];
    promises.push(query1(date));
    promises.push(query2());

    var results = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(results[0]); // query1
    console.log(results[1]); // query2

    res.send('blah');
});

function query1(date) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM job WHERE date = ?',[date] , function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(results);
            }
        }
    })
}

function query2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM vehicle ' , function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(results);
            }
        }
    })
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: For your solution is like I have to wait for first query then run second query then run my execution, but what I need is run first and second query at same time then run execution of jar file when first and second query data is return

Comment: This is where you'll need to use promises. Encapsulate all your database queries inside promise-returning functions, put them in an array of promises, and then run `var results = await Promise.all(array);`

Comment: I added a snippet for this. But this is incorporating quite a lot of concepts. You're going to have to read up on callbacks, promises, async/await, and specifically Promise.all(). Until you're comfortable with all of those, I'd probably think about just how much you need to get both of those calls in parallel.