# from google script to html

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a function in a .gs file:

```
function testReturn(){
 return "Finaly it works!";
}
```

and an other in an html file:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPost).testReturn();
  });

  /**/

  document.getElementById("go_button").addEventListener("click",functionGo);

  function functionGo(){

    var textToDisplay = google.script.run.testReturn();

    document.getElementById("input1_id").value = textToDisplay;   
  }

</script>
```

The return is always "undifined". How can I interact between gs and html script? (Of course I don't only want to return an integer, the project is to get a long text wrote with many functions, I'm just looking for a way to get the result and to dispaly it on a html).

Thanks you

Comment: Where is `createPost` function ?

Comment: Here's a complete example for you; https://stackoverflow.com/a/59865245/7215091

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not implementing the `createPost` function which is the callback function (because you set it in `withSuccessHandler` function [1]) that will receive the value returned in your `testReturn` function from code.gs.

For your html, the code below will update the input value as soon the page is loaded. It should work for you if you have an input element with id set to 'input1_id':

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPost).testReturn();
  });

  function createPost(returnedValue){
    document.getElementById("input1_id").value = returnedValue;   
  }
</script>
```

If what you want is to update the input value after a button is clicked, you can use this instead (assuming you have a button with 'go_button' as id):

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("go_button").addEventListener("click",functionGo);

  function functionGo(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPost).testReturn();
  }

  function createPost(returnedValue){
    document.getElementById("input1_id").value = returnedValue;   
  }

</script>
```

Basically, calling an Apps Script function (code.gs) from the html with `google.script.run` [2] won't directly return you the value, but rather you have to manage the response with a callback function set in one or more of the handler functions [1] (like `withSuccessHandler` in this example).

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second one is exactly what I was looking for