# why does callbak function exist?

Tags: c++, callback, blender

what's a callback function and when we should use them?

Comment: `callback` is just a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback is a function you can pass to the framework (in this case Blender).
The framework has the control and does some stuff.
Now, whenever appropriate, the framework (Blender) **calls** (executes it with given parameters) this function.
Therefore control is given **back** to your code.

(fictional) Example:
Handover a function that prints a text, say

```
void test() 
{
    std::cout << "Got called back!" << std::endl;
}
```

There will be some means of registering it, let's say

```
onRenderCallback(test);
```

Now, whenever Blender is rendering it will execute `test` and therefore print "`Got called back!`".

Commonly, the function takes some argument.
This can be used for mouse-input or similar.
For example, you could register a function that on any keypress takes the key code and does something with it.

Callbacks are especially useful in the context of the observer-pattern.