# What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I want to get a range from my sheet. As  recommended in [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), I am trying to get a array and manipulate it, but I'm confused:

```
const ss = Spreadsheet.getActive(),
  sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
  rg = sh.getRange("A1:C1"),//has 1,2,3
  values = rg.getValues();
console.log(values);
```

The logs show

```
[[1,2,3]]
```

As you can see I got all three elements. But, when I log the length of the array(`array.length`), it is just 1(instead of 3).  When I test existence of a element using `.indexOf` or `.includes`, It says -1 or `false`.

```js
const values = /*same as logged above*/[[1,2,3]];
console.log(values.indexOf(2));//got -1 expected 1
console.log(values.includes(1));//got false expected true
```

Why?

I have the same issue with `setValues()`.

```
rg.setValues([1,2,3]);//throws error
```

The error is

> "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues."

My specific Question is: What exactly does `getValues()`  return? Is it a special kind of array?

Comment: Answers with different approaches to the explain this concept are welcome.   Questions about this concept has been asked repeatedly. New answers to this question are appreciated.

Comment: New unique explanations of this concept maybe awarded a bounty based on the explanation quality.

Answer (score 13):

#### Documentation excerpts:

From The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), `getValues()` returns

> a two-dimensional array of values,

It **ALWAYS** returns a **two** dimensional array of values.

One dimensional array is

```
[1,2,3]
```

Two dimensional array is

```
[[1,2,3]]
//or
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

There is/are array(s) inside a array.

> indexed by row, then by column.

It is indexed by row first: i.e., The outer array has rows as inner array. Then each inner array has column elements. Consider the following simple spreadsheet:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1> | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2> | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3> | 3 | 4 | 5 |

`A1:A3` contains 3 rows  and each row contains 1 column element.  This is represented as `[[1],[2],[3]]`. Similarly, The following ranges represent the following arrays. Try to guess the array structure based on the A1 notation:

| A1 Notation | Number of Rows | Number of columns | Array Structure | array .length | array[0] .length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1:A3 | 3 | 1 | `[[1],[2],[3]]` | 3 | 1 |
| A1:C1 | 1 | 3 | `[[1,2,3]]` | 1 | 3 |
| A1:B2 | 2 | 2 | `[[1,2],[2,3]]` | 2 | 2 |
| B1:C3 | 3 | 2 | `[[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]` | 3 | 2 |
| A2:C3 | 2 | 3 | `[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]` | 2 | 3 |

Note  how the two dimension provides direction.
See live visualization below:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const test = {
  'A1:A3': [[1], [2], [3]],
  'A1:C1': [[1, 2, 3]],
  'A1:B2': [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
  ],
  'B1:C3': [
    [2, 3],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 5],
  ],
  'A2:C3': [
    [2, 3, 4],
    [3, 4, 5],
  ],
};

Object.entries(test).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`The range is ${key}`);
  console.table(value);
  console.info(`The above table's JavaScript array notation is ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
  console.log(`=================================`);
});
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

> The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String, depending on the value of the cell.

In the above example, We have  Spreadsheet Number type elements converted to  JavaScript number type. You can check spreadsheet type using [`=TYPE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375). Corresponding JavaScript type reference  is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

> Empty cells are represented by an empty string in the array.

Check using

```
console.log(values[0][0]==="")//logs true if A1 is empty
```

> Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array is indexed from [0][0].

Given the two dimensional array structure, to access a value, two indexes of format `array[row][column]` is needed. In the above table, if `A2:C3` is retrieved, To access `C3`, Use `values[1][2]`. `[1]` is second row in range A2:C3. Note that the range itself starts on second row. So, second row **in** the given range is row`3` `[2]`is third column `C`.

#### Notes:

- **Warning:**

> Retrieved values from a range is **always**  two dimensional **regardless of the range height or width**(even if it is just 1). `getRange("A1").getValues()` will represent `[[1]]`

- `setValues()` will accept the same array structure corresponding to the `range` to set. If a 1D array is  attempted, the error

> The parameters (number[]/string[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

is thrown.

- If the array does NOT exactly correspond to the range being set,i.e.,if each of the the inner array's length does not correspond to the  number of columns in the range or the outer array's length does not correspond to the number of rows in the range being set,  The error similar to the following is thrown:

> The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 5 but the range has 6.

- Related answers to the above error:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63770270
  - [Related Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D++The+number+of+columns+in+the+data+does+not+match+the+number+of+columns+in+the+range)
- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)/[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses strict type checking. They won't work when you compare primitives against array objects. You can use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the 2D array to a 1D one.  Alternatively, Use a plain old for-loop  to check something.

  ```js
  const values = [[1,2,3]].flat();//flattened
  console.log(values.indexOf(2));//expected 1
  console.log(values.includes(1));//expected true
  ```

#### References:

- [Basic reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)
- [MDN Arrays guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_Collections)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be populating an array that will be written to a spreadsheet range you can initialize it as a 2 dim array like so:

```
var dataTable = [[]] ;    // Data that will be written to sheet
```

Comment: You're only initializing the first element of array as 1D array. This is  unhelpful for any other elements of array.