# Push one array to the end of another

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am new to GAS. I have two arrays. AR1 has 7 cols and 16 rows. AR2 has 7 cols and 4 rows. I want to push the small array (AR2) to the bottom of the big array (AR1) for AR1 to have 7 cols and 20 rows. This is my code:

```
AR1.push(AR2);
```

When I check if there is new data by setting the values of AR1 into the active sheet (sh):

```
sh.getRange(1,1,AR1.length,AR1[0].length).setValues(AR1)
```

I get an error:
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 7.
And AR1 is written in the unchanged form in the active sheet with 7 cols and 16 rows.

It looks like AR2 is transposed in push command and/or not pushed to the end of AR1, but I don't understand why or how to fix it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Marios - I flagged the solution below in your reply.

Comment: Thanks Ruben - I saw that and yes, it had push.(...b), but I was unsure of the three dots in front,so did not type it that way. It works great.

Comment: thanks @MikeB. glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work:

```
AR1.push(...AR2);
```

References :

[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 3):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your issue is to push 2 dimensional array to the array.

  - For example, it supposes that the following 2 dimensional arrays are merged using `push()`.

    ```
      var ar1 = [["a1", "b1", "c1"],["a2", "b2", "c2"],["a3", "b3", "c3"]];
      var ar2 = [["a4", "b4", "c4"],["a5", "b5", "c5"]];
      ar1.push(ar2)
      console.log(ar1)
    ```
  - The result is as follows. You can see `ar2` is added to `ar1`. But this cannot be used for `setValues(ar1)`. This is directly the reason of your issue.

    ```
      [
          ["a1","b1","c1"],
          ["a2","b2","c2"],
          ["a3","b3","c3"],
          [["a4","b4","c4"],["a5","b5","c5"]]
      ]
    ```

In order to avoid this issue, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
AR1.push(AR2);
```

To:

```
AR1 = AR1.concat(AR2);
```

or

```
AR1 = [...AR1, ...AR2];
```

or

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(AR1, AR2);
```

- By this modification, when above sample values of `ar1` and `ar2` are used, the following result is obtained. By this modification, I think that your script of `sh.getRange(1,1,AR1.length,AR1[0].length).setValues(AR1)` also works.

  ```
    [
        ["a1","b1","c1"],
        ["a2","b2","c2"],
        ["a3","b3","c3"],
        ["a4","b4","c4"],
        ["a5","b5","c5"]
    ]
  ```

#### References:

- [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)