# Why doesn't my send email from google sheets script work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function sendEmail(){
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1").getRange("A1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
  var message = 'Test message';
  var subject = 'Test subject';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

When I try to run it, I get "Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail. (line 6, file "Send_Email")"

When I copy and paste the email address from Sheet 1, A1 into the spot occupied by the variable "emailAddress", the script works.

Comment: Take a look at the method signature of [the method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) and the error message again, and you will see where things went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Assuming that your sheet name is "Sheet 1" and not "Sheet1", the mistake you made is located here:

```
emailRange.getValues();
```

You should use instead:

```
emailRange.getValue();
```

**Solution:**

```
function sendEmail(){
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1").getRange("A1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  var message = 'Test message';
  var subject = 'Test subject';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

**Related:**

[What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)