# Need answer to “The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues” error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pls help me to understand what happening. I have code

```
    function splitWords() {
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var list_Key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Keys');
  if (list.getName() !== list_Key.getName()) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Для работы функции перейдите на страницу Keys');
  } else {
    var array = list.getRange('C2:C').getValues();
    var t_array = array.filter(String).lenght;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(array);
    var array1 = array.reduce(function (s, c) {
      var key = c[0];
      var keys = key.split(" ");
      for (var i in keys) {
        if (!s.includes(keys[i])) {                                       
          s.push(keys[i])
        }
      }
      return s;
    }, []);
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(array1);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,8,array1.length,array1[0].length).setValues(array1);
  }

}
```

When code comes to `setValues()` i have error.
The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Comment: As per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), `The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.` - could that be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612

Answer (score 1):

In your script, `array1` is 1 dimensional array. But it is required to be 2 dimensional array for `serValues`. I think that this is the reason of your issue. When you want to put the values of `array1` to the range from "H2" to the row direction, it is required to include each element of `array1` in an array. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
s.push(keys[i])
```

#### To:

```
s.push([keys[i]]);
```

#### Note:

- you want to put the values of `array1` to the range from "H2" to the column direction, how about the following modification?

  - From:

    ```
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,8,array1.length,array1[0].length).setValues(array1);
    ```
  - To:

    ```
      array1 = [array1];
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,8,array1.length,array1[0].length).setValues(array1);
    ```

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: But when I try to push like this ````s.push([keys[I]]);```` my function doesn't work correctly (((

Comment: @Alexander Vaschuk Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `my function doesn't work correctly`, unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to think of it. By the way, when you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your current script for replicating your issue, I think that it will help to think of the issue. How about this?

Comment: @Alexander Vaschuk By the way, in your script, `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()` is used. In this case, when the dialog is not closed, the next script is not run. Please be careful this.