# Script to convert specific cell content into uppercasing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function sortColumn() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('A3:G995');
  var value = range.getValue();
  range.setValue(value.toUpperCase());
};
```

Instead of turning the selected cell contents into uppercasing, the above script copies the content in A3 and pastes it to the rest of the cell. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

You can either turn the value of a **specific** cell to uppercase (as it is suggested by the title of the question) or turn the value of **every cell** within **a range of cells** to uppercase (as it is suggested by the body of the question).

**Solutions:**

If you want to turn the content of **A3** to uppercase:

```
function sortColumn() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A3');
  var value = range.getValue();
  range.setValue(value.toString().toUpperCase());
};
```

---

if you want to turn the content of **each cell** in **A3:G995** to uppercase:

```
function sortColumn() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A3:G995');
  var value = range.getValues();
  var valueCap=value.map(val => val.map(v=>v.toString().toUpperCase()));
  range.setValues(valueCap);
};
```

Comment: For the 2nd script, I got a warning of "v.toUpperCase is not a function" when tested.

Comment: Do you have V8 runtime enabled ?

Comment: @AUCH follow these instructions to enable V8 runtime and then run `sortColumn` again: http://prntscr.com/ukkki6

Comment: Still got the same warning after enabling V8 runtime :(

Comment: @AUCH are the values of type text in your sheet ? Because if they are numbers then you won't be able to turn it to a capital letter.

Comment: Right some cell contains number and symbol. How can I make the script ignore them?

Comment: @AUCH can you try `v.toString().toUpperCase()` ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

[`range.getValue()` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) says

> Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range.

So, the rest of the cells are ignored.

#### Solution:

Use [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) instead and [recurse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion) using  [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change  all values to uppercase and set back the modified array using [`setValues(arr)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvalues)

#### Sample script:

```
const values = range.getValues();
const func = e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(func) : String(e).toUpperCase();
range.setValues(func(values))
```

#### Related:

[What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)

```js
const values = /*Mock getValues*/ [['a','b'],['c','d']];
const func = e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(func) : String(e).toUpperCase();
const output = func(values);
console.info(output);
```

Comment: It says "e.toUpperCase is not a function" when tested. Did I miss something?

Comment: @AUCH As said in other answer comments, Numbers  need to be converted to strings. I updated my answer.