# How to get values in a column and put them into an array? Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to take a column of names and put them into an array.

```
function printDriver() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var driverArray = [];
 driverArray = sheet.getRange("H2:H34").getValues();
 driverArray.join('').split('');
```

I am unsure if this is the correct way to do it. Names only appear in `H2:H34` of sheet 0 in my spreadsheet. I want to get all those values, put them into an array and delete empty values but I believe that I end up with an empty array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution:

You just need to [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the empty cells.

You can do that with one line of code:

`driverArray = sheet.getRange("H2:H34").getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!="");`

```
function printDriver() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var driverArray = sheet.getRange("H2:H34").getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!="");
 }
```

`driverArray` is the desired array.

### Related:

[What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)

Comment: Love the simplicity - thanks!