# Return a specific row of a 2D array and write into Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with my array in Google Script.
I want to return for example only the first row of my 2D array. I tried it with adding '[0]' to get the first row of the array but it doesnt work. My desired output should be A30 = Lisa, B30 = 1, C30 = 1991

```
function testArray() {

var sht_test = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test');
var myArray = [
    ['Lisa',1,1991],
    ['Tim', 2,1989]
  ];

sht_test.getRange('A20:C21').setValues(myArray);  // returning the complete array works

//this doesnt work...
sht_test.getRange('A30:C30').setValues(myArray[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Issue / Explanation:**

[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) **accepts** a **2D** array like `myArray`:

```
var myArray = [
    ['Lisa',1,1991],
    ['Tim', 2,1989]
  ];
```

However, `myArray[0]` will give you a **1D** array:

```
['Lisa',1,1991]
```

To make it **2D**, simply wrap it up with `[]`:

```
[['Lisa',1,1991]]
```

It may seem weird, but you must make it 2D because this is what [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) accepts.

---

### Solution:

Use this instead:

```
sht_test.getRange('A30:C30').setValues([myArray[0]]);
```

---

### Highly Related:

[What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)

Comment: Hi Marios, thanks for your solution. This is exactly what i was searching for. I knew it must be something 'weird' :-)