# Pipedrive API GET request setValues of array in Google Sheet not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pipedrive-api

I have this array that I'm pulling from Pipedrive using API: [John Smith, [555-867-5309, 444-867-5309], [john@gmail.com, john@yahoo.com]]
I want this array to populate to the Google sheet like so:

```
         |       A        |               B                |                    C               |
=========+========+========+========+========+========+========+========+========+===============
    1    |   John Smith   |   555-867-5309, 444-867-5309   |   john@gmail.com, john@yahoo.com   |
```

I'm using setValues but am getting an error that the number[] doesn't match the method signature for range.setValues so it's not pasting anything to the sheet.

Here's my code. It works to pull in the data. I just want to pull the three fields (name, phone, and email) of all the data it returns.

```
var URL = "https://....pipedrive.com";
var API_TOKEN = "...";
function test() {
  var sheeturl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheeturl);
  var leadsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Leads Sheet');
  var personData = [];
  
  var personurl = URL +'/v1/persons/3812?api_token='+ API_TOKEN;
  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "contentType": "application/json",
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(personurl, options);
  response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var name = response.data.name;
  var phone = [response.data.phone.map(phone => phone.value).join(', ')];
  var email = [response.data.email.map(email => email.value).join(', ')];
  var personArray = [name, phone, email];
  Logger.log(personArray);
  personData.push(personArray);
  leadsSheet.getRange(leadsSheet.getLastRow()+1, 5, personData.length, personData[0].length).setValues(personData); //writes to end of sheet
}
```

The log from this is: `[20-10-25 16:29:34:339 EDT] [John Smith, [555-867-5309, 444-867-5309], [john@gmail.com, john@yahoo.com]]` but nothing populates to the sheet; it remains blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

`personArray` returns:

`[John Smith, [555-867-5309, 444-867-5309], [john@gmail.com, john@yahoo.com]]`

but your goal is to return:

`[[John Smith, 555-867-5309,444-867-5309, john@gmail.com,john@yahoo.com]]`

where `555-867-5309,444-867-5309` and `john@gmail.com,john@yahoo.com` is a **single** `string` element separated by comma.

To convert: `['555-867-5309', '444-867-5309']` to `'555-867-5309,444-867-5309'` you can use [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).

---

### Solution:

Replace:

`var personArray = [name, phone, email];`

with:

`var personArray = [name,phone.toString(),email.toString()]`

**Complete snippet:**

```
var URL = "https://....pipedrive.com";
var API_TOKEN = "...";
function test() {
  var sheeturl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheeturl);
  var leadsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Leads Sheet');
  var personData = [];
  
  var personurl = URL +'/v1/persons/3812?api_token='+ API_TOKEN;
  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "contentType": "application/json",
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(personurl, options);
  response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var name = response.data.name;
  var phone = [response.data.phone.map(phone => phone.value).join(', ')];
  var email = [response.data.email.map(email => email.value).join(', ')];
  var personArray = [name,phone.toString(),email.toString()];
  Logger.log(leadsSheet.getLastRow()) // <- this should give the last row with content. Scroll down to your sheet to confirm.
  personData.push(personArray);
  leadsSheet.getRange(leadsSheet.getLastRow()+1, 5, personData.length, personData[0].length).setValues(personData); //writes to end of sheet
}
```

---

### Minimal reproducible example:

```
function myFunction(){

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Leads Sheet');
var personData=[];
var name = 'John Smith' 
var phone = ['555-867-5309', '444-867-5309'];
var email = ['john@gmail.com', 'john@yahoo.com'];
var personArray = [name,phone.toString(),email.toString()];
personData.push(personArray);
sheet.getRange(1,1,personData.length,personData[0].length).setValues(personData);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

### Related Article:

[What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it works in a new standalone spreadsheet. But when I try to use that exact same function in my existing script/sheet setup, it doesn't do anything. I'm not even modifying the function - I just pasted it in and hit 'run' for that function and nothing populated on the sheet. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: If it does not drop any error, then make sure that `Logger.log(leadsSheet.getLastRow())` gives the last row with number. Scroll also down to the `Leads Sheet` to see if the data is pasted somewhere in the bottom of the sheet. The new data should be pasted to `Leads Sheet`, therefore make sure that this sheet exists and `leadsSheet.getLastRow()` returns the expected number which is the last row with content. @823g4n8901

Comment: @823g4n8901 I updated the Complete snippet in the solution part of my answer. The only thing you need to make sure is that you have a sheet with **exactly** the name `Leads Sheet` and `Logger.log(leadsSheet.getLastRow())` to make sure that you are getting the last row with content.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. The problem was my sheet wasn't referencing correctly - I was using the get sheet by url way of doing it and for some reason it wouldn't work within the function, but when I referenced the sheet by url outside the function it worked. So your answer was perfect.