# Cannot get values of a column with getRange and getValues

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var items = data.getRange(1,14,1,lc).getValues()[0];
var names = cdata.getRange(52, 1, 28,1).getValues()[0];
```

When I log 'items' I get the desired information populated in a single array.
When I try to get the 'names' in a column using a similar method I can only get the first cell in a single array or all of the desired cells in an array of arrays.

example of items

[item1,item2,item3,...]

example of names

[name1] or [[name1],[name2],[name3],[...]]

Why am I not able to use the same method to accurately retrieve the names in a column as I did in the row? How do I fix this and get the desired result? How do I get names to return the data in the cells as I did with items?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)

Comment: getRange(row,column,#rows,#columns) and getValues() can get just the values in the range or [row][column] but I'm not 100% sure about getValues. Tried doing [0][0] instead of just [0] and I still got the one name.

Comment: didn't realize it was a link sorry. It did give me some more insight and answers part of my question. Still need  to figure out a way to flatten the array then since .flat isn't a thing in google scripts.

Comment: `getValues().flat()`

Comment: That worked thanks! Didn't think it would work because it didn't show up in the list when typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have 1 column for names combined with []. That will return a [] result from a a structure like [ [][][] ] (not [ [] ]). If your items have multiple rows, you'll get the entire first row [,,,], as you suggest in items.

```
var items = data.getRange(1,14,1,lc).getValues()[0];
var names = cdata.getRange(52, 1, 28,1).getValues()[0];
```

That's more a diagnosis than an answer. Basically, you're getting what you should get from that, but I think you want it transposed. Various ways to do that.

But will this work?

```
// flatten(flatten()) works for 2-level nesting, and so on
function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
  return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}
```

reference: https://gist.github.com/MauricioMoraes/225afcc9dd72acf1511f

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work when I wrote it as follows:

      var names = cdata.getRange(52, 1, 28,1).getValues();
 // flatten(flatten()) works for 2-level nesting, and so on
  function flatten(names){
    return [].concat.apply([], names);
  Logger.log(flatten);
}

Comment: I was able to use var names = cdata.getRange(52, 1, 28,1).getValues().flat(); to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use this instead:

```
var names = cdata.getRange(52, 1, 28,1).getValues().flat();
```