# highlighting maximum values in a specific column using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`m trying to write a script that can find the maximum value in a specific column (proportion column in the given dataset) and highlight the cell accordingly.

Below is where I am at so far

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sh.getRange("G2:G17");
var values = range.getValues();
var newRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 7, values.length, 1).getValues();
var maximumproportion = Math.max.apply(Math, newRange);
var maxarr = [];
maxarr.push(maximumproportion)
var backgrounds = [];
var fontColors = [];

range.sort([{column:7, ascending: false}]); // sort by number is column 7

if (newRange === maxarr) {
  backgrounds.push(["green"])
}else{
  backgrounds.push([null])
}
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,7,values.length,1).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

---

And below is the dataset I am using for this
[image]

so if the above code properly worked, it should`ve highlighted the first row in the last column which is 0.27% as this is the maximum value found in this column.

For the below part, I`ve also tried using for loop. But no luck there

Can someone please advise on how i can get this work?

```
// find the max value in Column G
  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    console.log(newRange[i][0])
    if (newRange[i] === maxarr[i]) {
    backgrounds.push(["green"]);
    } else {
    backgrounds.push([null]);
    }
 }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,7,16,1).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Comment: Try Math.max(...newRange.flat()); [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/ Your comparison `if` statements are all wrong. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: @TheMaster - thanks for the link. That helped. I used the pasted code to make it work  -  for (var i = 0; i < newRange.length; i++) {
  if (newRange[i][0] === maximumproportion) {
      colors.push(["#FFDD88"]);
  } else {
      colors.push([null]);
      
  }
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(colors)
}

Comment: @Jason1993 Consider adding a answer with explanations. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer 1

You can highlight the maximum value in a specific column using [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

**Steps**

1. Go to `Format > Conditional formatting`
2. Select the range to apply the format
3. Select `Custom formula is` in `Format cells if`
4. Apply `=(G:G)=MAX(G:G)` to select the cell with highest value

### Answer 2

You can get and highlight the highest value in a simple way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sh.getRange("D2:D14")
  var values = range.getValues();
  var merged = [].concat.apply([], values);
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math,merged)
  var maxid = merged.indexOf(max)
  range.getCell(maxid+1,1).setBackgroundRGB(0,255,0)
}
```

**Explanation**

1. `var merged = [].concat.apply([], values)` transforms an array of arrays into an array of integers.
2. `var max = Math.max.apply(Math,merged)` gets the highest value of the range
3. `var maxid = merged.indexOf(max)` gets the index of the highest value
4. `range.getCell(maxid+1,1).setBackgroundRGB(0,255,0)` change the background of the desired cell. Keep in mind that the index of the array starts from 0 and the index from the cell from 1, so you have to sum 1 to the index. Furthermore, in RGB, green is equal to `zero red, full green, zero blue`.

Comment: thanks for the help :) I really like your code approach here. This is much more simpler and straight to the point solution...

Comment: If you find my solution useful please mark it as accepted so the community will know that it helped you.