# GAS map array with conditions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array.prototype.map

I have the following array

```
const wrangeValues = sheet.getRange(workdayFlagRow, firstColumn, 1, lastColumn).getValues();
```

which displays in the log as `[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]`

I want to create a new array with Ys or Ns like this:

```
const map1 = wrangeValues.map(x => (x === 1 ? 'y' : 'n'));
```

`Logger.log(map1)` outputs as `[n]`

Expected output: `[[y, n, n, n, n, y]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wrangeValues` is a 2D array. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/). Use:

```
const map1 = [wrangeValues[0].map(x => (x === 1 ? 'y' : 'n'))]
```