# Googls Sheets: Create copy button to copy a range of rows in a specific column from one sheet to another one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets I am trying to make a copy button that once clicked it should launch a script code in order to copy some values in a specific column (for example 20 specific cells starting from a specific row) and paste them to the next empty column in another sheet (sheet 2) starting from a specific row.

Each time the button is pressed it copies the results to the next empty column in sheet 2 so it doesn't copy over the previous pasted result.

Just the value or text from these cells on sheet 1:
C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21,C22,C23

Into corresponding cells on sheet 2:
F11:F30

C4 will go into F11, C5 into F12, and so on ..... and finally C23 into F30

Next time the copy button is clicked, again values from C4:C23 in sheet 1 will be copied to the next emtpy column in sheet 2, that is, G11:G30.

Comment: What've you tried so far? Can you share a Spreadsheet as example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can find the explanation in the comments:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // get sheet objects for Sheet1 and Sheet2
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // use your sheet name for sheet1
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // use your sheet name for sheet2
  // get the data from Sheet1 C4:C23
  const data = sh1.getRange('C4:C23').getValues();
  // copy the data to Sheet2 starting from row 11 after the last column with content
  sh2.getRange(11,sh2.getLastColumn()+1,data.length,1).setValues(data); 
}
```

**References:**

- [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn())
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)