# how to get maximum index of array in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to get the values in a row into an array. For this I used the appscript in googlesheet. After checking the length of this `rowtemp` array, the answer is 1.
But I want to find the number of children inside. And if the element in "temp" is the same as the one in "rowtemp" then you need to find its column number
I used following code.
[image]

```
    function rangeExa(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet4");

  var temp = ss.getRange("A11:B22").getValues();
  Logger.log(temp);
  Logger.log(temp.length);
  Logger.log(temp[3][0]);

  var rowTemp = ss.getRange("D25:O25").getValues();
  Logger.log(rowTemp);
  Logger.log(rowTemp.length);
  Logger.log(rowTemp[0][2]);
  Logger.log(rowTemp);

  for(i=0; i<=rowTemp.length; i++){
  if(temp[3][0] == rowTemp[0][i]){
    Logger.log("yessss");
  }return;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Your title, the description and the code are not describing the same problem so I am confused. I think if you provide the output of the expected data we will be able to solve the issue faster. However, `rowTemp` is an array of a single array (row) this is why `rowTemp.length` is 1. If you want to find the number of elements in that array, you should do `rowTemp[0].length`. Also why do you have a `return` statement at the end of the code? are you planning to use this as a custom formula or is this a helper function of another function? Either way, you need to return something or set the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I explained in detail in the comment section, your goal is not clear.

However, there is a clear issue in the code an that relates to the length of `rowTemp`.

`rowTemp` is an array of a single array because it concers a single row. In other words, it has the format of `[["High","Not High",..]]`. Therefore, `rowTemp.length` will give you `1` since there is only one row in this array. If you want to iterate over the columns, you need to use `rowTemp[0].length`:

```
  for(i=0; i<rowTemp[0].length; i++){
    if(temp[3][0] == rowTemp[0][i]){
     Logger.log("yessss");
     Logger.log(i+4); // column number if there is a match
    }
  }
```

The above `for` loop will check if `36` appears in `D25:O25` and it will output `yessss` if it does in the Logs page.

- Also use `i<rowTemp[0].length` instead of `i<=rowTemp[0].length` because the last index of your array is `rowTemp[0].length-1` otherwise you will get `undefined`.

**Related:**

[What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)

Comment: thank you. If this is true, how do we get the corresponding column value of "i"?

Comment: @TipVisor I updated the code. You need `i+4` because your data starts from column D (column 4).